# How to print 5 consecutive lines after a pattern in file using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I would like to search for a pattern in a file and prints 5 lines after finding that pattern.

I need to use `awk` in order to do this.

Example:

File Contents:

```
.
.
.
.
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
#Line5
.
.
.
```

How do I parse through a file and print only the above mentioned lines?
Do I use the NR of the line  which contains "PATTERN" and keep incrementing upto 5 and print each line in the process.
Kindly do let me know if there is any other efficient wat to do it in Awk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Another way to do it in AWK:

```
awk '/PATTERN/ {for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}' inputfile
```

in `sed`:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/{n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p}' inputfile
```

in GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/,+7p' inputfile
```

or

```
sed -n '1{x;s/.*/####/;x};/PATTERN/{:a;n;p;x;s/.//;ta;q}' inputfile
```

The `#` characters represent a counter. Use one fewer than the number of lines you want to output.

Comment: Nice use of the hold space as a countdown.

Comment: What if I want to match the pattern only in the last column ?
For example, print the next line iff last column ($NF) is E. I want to ignore E in other columns.

Comment: @lovedynasty: `awk '$NF ~ /^E$/ {for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}' inputfile` should work.

Comment: If you are going to use sed (Gnu sed) then sed -n `/PATTERN/,+5p' file` might fit the bill. Or `sed -n /PATTERN/{N;N;N;N;N;p}' file`.

Comment: This `awk` answer is much more flexible, making it more useful than the more compact versions which are nice on their own and to the point of the question. But I could do much more starting from this particular syntax: find pattern, print next two lines and combine them into one line, with specific print conditions (fields) for each one.

Comment: @Kjuly: Note that potong's uses capital N's which appends to the pattern space (lower n replaces the pattern space).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson ah right, let me delete original comment and append it here again: Just as a note here for sed's case, if you're under Mac OS (which I heard uses BSD sed), need extra `;` after `p`, i.e., `sed -n '/PATTERN/{n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p;}'` inputfile, or like @potong said, `sed -n '/regex/{N;N;N;N;N;p;}'` file.

Answer (score 15):

```
awk '
{ 
    if (lines > 0) {
        print;
        --lines;
    }
}

/PATTERN/ {
    lines = 5
}

' < input
```

This yields:

```
#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
#Line5
```

Comment: There is an issue with this code. If the PATTERN repeats after less than 5 lines, the loop restarts rather than finish printing all 5 lines. Answer by Dennis works better.

Comment: @Ruchi  You're right. Dennis' is a better answer (and I upvoted it). I think it came in after @tomkaith13 accepted my own. I can only assume that my answer solves his problem, even if it is not the most resilient.

Comment: @Ruchi: But Dennis' answer doesn't print all 5 lines following the second occurence in this case. I think it depends on what you  want. You might want to print the first lines after the second occurence (those that are within the 5 lines range of the previous one) twice: once for the first (including the second occurence) and twice for the second occurence. This really depends on the use case and wasn't specified by the OP.

Comment: What if I want to match the pattern only in the last column ? For example, print the next line iff last column ($NF) is E. I want to ignore E in other columns

Comment: @lovedynasty: This is a different question and should be asked as a fresh post. Have you tried `$NF ~ /PATTERN/ {` ?

Comment: I made it work by using && $NF~/PATTERN/ works. Thanks

Comment: @lovedynasty: You shouldn't need `/PATTERN/ && `!

Answer (score 13):

`grep "PATTERN" search-file -A 5` will do the job for you if decide to give grep a chance.

Edit: You can call grep using `system()` function from inside your `awk` script as well.

Comment: I thought that, too. But that yields the line containing 'PATTERN', which doesn't seem to match the requirements.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: `grep -A6 | tail -5` ?

Comment: @ninjalj: What happens when 'PATTERN' appears inside the input file more than once?

Comment: @anubhava: forking to `grep` within `awk`? Yuck!

Comment: @Johnsyweb: No I won't recommend calling grep from awk either but since OP specifically said that he needs to use awk only that's why just added that edit line.

Comment: I think grep -A is a gnu extension, you won't find that option on AIX  or Solaris standard installs, but I don't have access to those OS's to confirm this right now. Cordially

Comment: You can install gnu utils on other unixes as well. Very neat info thanks. Using grep on a regular basis but didn't know it had -A and -B

Comment: @ninjalj: Shouldn't it be `grep -A5 | tail -5`? GNU `grep` 2.14 over here.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Besides the initial line that matched `PATTERN`, `grep -A5` will result in the same output as your code. However, things get more complicated with multiple occurences.

Answer (score 11):

`awk` to the rescue!

to print with the pattern line (total 6 lines)

```
$ awk '/^####PATTERN/{c=6} c&&c--' file

####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
#Line5
```

to skip pattern and print the next five lines

```
$ awk 'c&&c--; /^####PATTERN/{c=5}' file

#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
#Line5
```

Comment: Excellent improvement over Dennis' answer!

Comment: @karakfa, never seen statements before patterns in awk `awk 'c&&c--; /^####PATTERN/{c=5}'`. Can we write any type of statement before pattern like print or assignment etc  ?

Comment: Not a statement but any expression that has a value (which will be interpreted as truth value).  Corresponding statement to the expression will be the default statement, which is `{print}`.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** didn't notice `PATTERN` shouldn't be part of the output.

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk '{if(a-->0){print;next}} /qmaild/{a=5}'
```

or

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk ' found && NR-6 < a{print} /qmaild/{a=NR;found=1}'
```

The shortest I can come up with is:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk 'a-->0;/qmaild/{a=5}'
```

Read as *a tends to 0. /qmaild/ sets a to 5* :-)

Comment: Nice usage of the [`-->`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/78845) operator! But why are you using [`cat`](http://uuoc.com/)?

Comment: To have the input clearly separate from the command the OP is interested in.

Comment: For the benefit of less experienced readers, surely the --> is the -- operator appended to the 'a' variable, with > representing 'greater than', yes? Awk can parse such concatenated syntax. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Quick&dirty solution: `awk '/PATTERN/ {i=0} { if (i<=5) {print $0}; i+=1} BEGIN {i=6}'`

Answer (score 0):

As limited as Johnsyweb's solution but using a different approach and GNU `awk`'s advanced feature allowing full RegEx record separators resulting in a piece of code that, IMHO, is very `awk`-ish:

```sh
awk -F\\\n '{NF=5}NR-1' RS="PATTERN[^\n]*." OFS=\\\n
```

So if you want a stable solution that is also readable, go along with Dennis Williamson's answer (+1 for that one) but maybe you too simply enjoy the beauty of `awk` when looking at lines like this.