# Extract Nth line after matching pattern

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I want to extract the Nth line after a matching pattern using `grep`, `awk` or `sed`.

For example I have this piece of text:

```
      Revision:
      60000<br />
```

And I want to extract 60000.

I tried `Revision:([a-z0-9]*)\s*([0-9]){5}` which matches the Revision together with the revision number but when I pass it to grep: `grep Revision:([a-z0-9]*)\s*([0-9]){5} file.html` I get nothing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To `extract the Nth line after a matching pattern` you want:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' file
```

e.g.

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/Revision:/{c=5}' file
```

would print the 5th line after the text "Revision:"/.

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001) for more information.

Comment: `c&&!--c` is equivalent to `c!=0 && --c==0` and `c&&c--` is equivalent to `c!=0 && --c>=0`; the alternatives may be easier to understand.

Comment: One caveat is that if a pattern appears again before reaching the next N'th line, the counter is reset and the earlier appearances are forgotten. For example, in c), if N=10 and the pattern is in lines 21 and 28, then only line 38 will be printed but not line 31. To deal with this, you can use `awk '/pattern/{p[NR+N]=1} NR in p'` (simpler) or `awk '/pattern/{p[NR+N]=1} NR in p{print; delete p[NR]}'` (keeps the memory usage bounded).

Comment: How to modify f.) to not to print the line with pattern (it is doing so now)?

Comment: As answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895234/combine-v-option-for-grep-with-a-option the modification is `awk '/abc/ {c=0} c++>4' file`

Comment: @Betlista No, you just swap the parts that recognize the condition and skip lines to get the rearranged `awk '/pattern/{c=N} c&&c--{next} 1' file`. What you wrote, `awk '/abc/ {c=0} c++>4' file`, does something quite different, e.g. it'll unconditionally skip the first 5 lines of input.

Answer (score 6):

**Printing the `lnb`<sup>th</sup> line after first blank/empty line:**

Index of line to print (in bash shell):

```
lnb=2
```

- Using `sed`:

  ```
  sed -ne '/^\s*$/{:a;n;0~'"$lnb"'!ba;p;q}' my_file`
  ```
- Using `perl`:

  ```
  perl -ne '/^\s+$/ && $k++;$k!=0 && $k++ && $k=='"$lnb"'+2 && (print,last)' my_file`
  ```

**Printing the `lnb`<sup>th</sup> line after regular-expression match:**

- Using `sed`:

  ```
  sed -ne '/regex/{:a;n;0~'"$lnb"'!ba;p;q}' my_file
  ```
- Using `perl`:

  ```
  perl -ne '/regex/ && $k++;$k!=0 && $k++ && $k=='"$lnb"'+2 && (print,last)' my_file
  ```

  *Bonus 1, Windows PowerShell* (install Perl first) :

  ```
  $lnb=2

  perl -ne "/regex/ && `$k++;`$k!=0 && `$k++ && `$k==$lnb+2 && (print,last)" my_file
  ```

  *Bonus 2, Windows DOS command line* :

  ```
  set lnb=2

  perl -ne "/regex/ && $k++;$k!=0 && $k++ && $k==%lnb%+2 && (print,last)" my_file
  ```

**Printing ALL `lnb`<sup>th</sup> lines after regular-expression match:**

- Using `perl`(bash example):

  ```
  perl -ne '/regex/ && $k++;$k!=0 && $k++ && $k=='"$lnb"'+2 && (print,$k=0)' my_file
  ```

Comment: Nice work. Also take your time to take the [tour] to see what Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: Thanks, I will take.

Answer (score 1):

I like solutions I can learn to redo, without having to google for it every time. This solution is not perfect, but uses simple grep commands that I can write from memory.

```
grep -A7 "searchpattern" file | grep -B1 "^--$" | grep -v "^--$"
```

You can change the 7 to the nth line you want after the search pattern. It then searches for the "group separator" `--` and shows the last line before that. Then remove the group separators.

The only case this does not work correctly is if your data contains lines with only "--".