# Explain awk command

Tags: unix, awk

Today I was searching for a command online to print next two lines after a pattern and I came across an awk command which I'm unable to understand.

```
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '_&&_--;/PATTERN/{_=2}' input
```

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 38):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for the answer that was duplicated here.

Answer (score 16):

`_` is being used as a variable name here (valid but obviously confusing). If you rewrite it as:

```
awk 'x && x--; /PATTERN/ { x=2 }' input
```

then it's a little easier to parse. Whenever `/PATTERN/` is matched, the variable gets set to `2` (and that line is not output) - that's the second half. The first part fires when `x` is not zero, and decrements `x` as well as printing the current line (the default action, since that clause does not specify an action).

The end result is to print the two lines immediately following any match of the pattern, as long as neither of those lines also matches the pattern.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put the command prints a number of lines after a given regular expression expression match not including the matched line.

The number of lines is specified in the block `{_=2}` and the variable `_` is set to 2 if the line matches `PATTERN`. Every line read after a matching line causes `_` to be decremented. You can read `_&&_--` as if `_` is greater than zero then minus one from it, this happens for every line after a match until `_` hits zero. It's quite simple when you replace the variable `_` with a more sensible name like `n`.

A simple demo should make it clear (print the 2 lines that follow any line matching `foo`):

```
$ cat file
foo
1
2
3
foo
a
b
c

$ awk 'n && n--;/foo/{n=2}' file
1
2
a
b
```

So `n` is only True when it gets set to 2 after matching a line with `foo` then it decrements `n` and prints the current line. Due to `awk` having short circuit evaluation `n` is only decrement when `n` is True *(n>0)* so the only possible values in this case for `n` are 2,1 or 0.

Awk has the following structure `condition{block}` and when a condition is evaluated True then block is executed for the current record. If you don't provide a block `awk` uses the default block `{print $0}` so `n && n--;` is a condition without a block that only evaluates to True for `n` lines after the regular expression match. The semi-colon just delimits the condition `n&&n--` for the conditions `/foo/` make it explicit that the condition has no block.

To print the two lines following the match including the match you would do:

```
$ awk '/foo/{n=3} n && n--' file
foo
1
2
foo
a
b
```

*Extra extra:* the fact that the full path of `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` is used tells me this code is intended for a Solaris machine as the `/usr/bin/awk` is totally broken and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation**

`awk` expressions have the following form:

```
condition action; NEXT_EXPRESSION
```

If conditon is true action(s) will be executed. Further note, if condition is true but action has been omitted `awk` will execute `print` (the default action).

You have two expressions in your code that will get executed on every line of input:

```
_&&_--          ;
/PATTERN/{_=2}
```

Both are separated by a `;`. As I told that default action `print` will happen if the action is omitted it is **the same as**:

```
_&&_--    {print};
/PATTERN/ {_=2}
```

In your example `_` is a variable name, which gets initialized by `0` on the first line of input, before it's first usage - automatically by awk.

First condition would be `(0) && (0)`.. What results in the condition being false, as `0 && 0` evaluates to `false` and awk will not print.

If the pattern is found, `_` will be set to `2` which makes the first condition being `(2) && (2)` on the next line and `(1) && (1)` on the next line after that line as `_` is decremented after the condition has being evaluated. Both are evaluating to `true` and awk will print those lines.

However, nice puzzle ;)

Comment: Slight mistake, post-decrement has higher order or precedence that logical AND so explicitly `(0) && (0--)` as `(0&&0)--` evaluates to -1.

Comment: nice to know.. let me enhance the post in that way.

Comment: @sudo_O `awk '_&&_--; 1{printf "%i\n", _};/Pattern/{_=2}' input.txt` I don't understand the output of the line above. If decrement takes place before (what is conform to awk docs, you are right), then the right side of `&&` should be 1 in the first test and 0 in the second test after the pattern has matched. So I would expect that just one line will be printed.. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's subtle but maybe this helps you http://ideone.com/JlT8BG notice the pattern of `n` before the condition `0,2,1,0,2,1,0` that is because the **post**-decrement happens **post** (after) the condition have been evaluated. To `skip` or to `echo` is decided first then `n` is decremented.

Comment: @sudo_O Yeah have thought about this while having a walk.. Operator precedence has nothing to do with the increment action happening before or after the condition has been evaluated. Sorry, shame on me I should know about that! ;) ... Will now update the post so that it is completely correct...

Answer (score 2):

Wonderfully obscure. Will update when time allows.

`_` is being used as a variable name. The `&&` is a logical operator that has 2 true actions run together. Once the value of _ is reduced to zero, the 2nd half of the && is false and no output is generated.

```
print -- "
xxxxx
yyyy
PATTERN
zzz
aa
bbb
ccc
ddd" | awk '_&&_--;/PATTERN/{_=2}'
```

**output**

```
zzz
aa
```

**debug version**

```
print -- "
xxxxx
yyyy
PATTERN
zzz
aa
bbb
ccc
ddd" | awk '_&&_--;{print "_="_;print _&&_};/PATTERN/{_=2;print "_="_ }'
```

**output**

```
_=
0
_=
0
_=
0
_=
0
_=2
zzz
_=1
1
aa
_=0
0
_=0
0
_=0
0
_=0
0
```