# sed search a range and print first set

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file like as follows

```
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
and it follows and no standard other than myname word.
```

Now I want to print the first set of search from myname to till myname found as below.

```
myname
_       something
_       something
_
```

I tried using the following but it is not working.

```
sed -n -e '/myname/,/myname/ p' file
```

It prints all the sets.

Tried this also but not worked.

```
sed -n '/myname/,$ p;/myname/q'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk  '/myname/{if(b) exit; else b=1}1' filename



$ cat temp.txt
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something

$ awk  '/myname/{if(b) exit; else b=1}1' temp.txt
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk '/myname/{++c}c<2' file
```

```
$ cat file
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
```

```
$ awk '/myname/{++c}c<2' file
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
```

If you file is too big then:

```
awk '/myname/{++c}c==2{exit}1' file
```

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru You're welcome. Make sure you read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407890/explain-awk-command/18409469#18409469). It contains many valuable gems!

Comment: i think this only works if no lines exist prior to the 1st `myname`, cuz those extra lines would also get printed since `c == 0` for them, which satisifies `c < 2`

Answer (score 2):

```
mawk '(_+=/myname$/)*_>_{ exit }_'
```

---

```
 1  myname
 2  _       something
 3  _       something
 4  _       something
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did there? :D

Comment: @tink : it's basically the same idea, but I exit when `x < x^2`, something that fails for all values within `[0, 1]`,  inclusive of both ends and all fractions in between, but passes for everyone else, so it'll exit when it increments to a 2. The final underscore `…}_` ensures it only starts printing after seeing the 1st `myname`, and ignore all lines prior to that

Comment: @tink : and luckily for `awk`, the lack of actual boolean data type is a blessing in disguise, cuz it means instead of having to perform another layer of type conversions, all boolean conditions evaluate to numeric `0` or `1`, so I could directly `add` the outcome of the pattern evaluation, and make that my printing indicator flag. Unlike most shells or `perl`, the variable `_` is absolutely no special, so you can use it for anything

Comment: Very impressive. I still don't fully understand what it all does - what's e.g. the point of that `*`?

Comment: @tink : multiplication

Comment: @tink : does this mapping help ? `((_ += /myname$/) * _) > (_) { exit } _` ::::::::::::::::::: `'/myname$/ { ++flag } flag < flag^2 { exit } flag != 0 { print }'` ::::::::::::: none of those are special obscure operators. they're just add-assign `+=`, `regex` pattern check against full input row `/…../`, multiplication `*`, greater than `>`, and the evaluation of a flag to invoke default print action block.

Comment: Yes, it does help a lot :) Maybe you should include those explanatory words in the actual answer ... as it is it's about as legible as perl code ;)

Comment: @tink : `perl` is a chaotic mess where `_` is reserved, having to say `my` this `my` that, user-defined functions couldn't be called `"functions"` but `"sub(routine)"` instead, `say` vs. `print` differ by barely anything, and the amount of quote or quote-like operators is beyond repair.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/myname/{:a;n;//Q;$!ba}' file
```

Look for the pattern `myname` then set up a loop that, prints the current line, quits (but does not print) if the new current line contains the above pattern or loops.

An alternative, using the grep-like option `-n`:

```
sed -n '/myname/{:a;p;n;//q;ba}' file
```

Comment: @ potong: this solution looks  a good sed option , can you please elaborate how this command is working ? and what does //Q signify in between .

Comment: @protong: From what I understand by //Q is an empty search expression   with a 'quit' flag.  Is it like when you pass an empty search expression  it uses the   last used search expression ( which is myname in this example ) ?  as I used  this   sed '/myname/{:a;n;/myname/Q;$!ba}'  and it also looks to be working the same way.

Comment: @user3369871 [correct](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses)

Answer (score 1):

I have some **sed only solutions** for you:

Given this input file

```bash
$ cat file
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
_       something
myname
_       something
```

```bash
sed -n -e '/myname/,$ { 1,/myname/p }' file
```

produces this output

```
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
myname
```

Adding `| sed '$d'` will delete the last line, so

`sed -n -e '/myname/,$ { 1,/myname/p }' file | sed '$d'`

gives this output

```
myname
_       something
_       something
_       something
```

**Explanation**

`sed -n` supresses line output `/myname/,$` selects all the lines from `myname` to the end of the file.

From the selected lines  `{ 1,/myname/p }` will print all the lines to the next `myname` and finally `| sed ‘$d’` deletes the last line of the previous command.

Obviously, this will also work where first and second *regexs* are different.

**Bonus**

```bash
sed -n -e '/myname/,$ { 1,/myname/ { /myname/!p } }' file
```

prints this:

```bash
_       something
_       something
_       something
```

**Why the original selection isn’t working**

Originally I couldn’t understand why your script wasn’t working. I had been trying something similar myself and had been searching for reasons why it wasn’t and just assumed that `sed` was, inexplicably, broken.

Then I realised: `sed` processes the whole file and applies your (and my!) patterns repeatedly, it finds several examples of `myname … myname` and prints all of them!

If the start and end /regexs/ are different then the expample below works (say your file had a mixture of myname and othername)

```bash
sed -n -e '/myname/,/othername/ { p; /othername/q }' file
```

You will still have to delete the last line of output if you don’t want the line containing *othername*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Bash solution.

```
n=0
while read line; do
    [[ $line == myname ]] && ((n++))
    [ $n -gt 1 ] && break
    echo $line
done < file
```