# Removing lines between tags in a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I have many text files containing annotations. The original text is marked with lines containing the words:

```
START OF TEXT OF PASSAGE 1

END OF TEXT OF PASSAGE 1
```

Obviously I can search each document for the phrase `START OF TEXT` and delete everything up to it. Then search for `END OF TEXT` and start selecting text for deletion until I get to the next `START OF TEXT`.

I have come up with this design so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="START OF PROJECT"
b="END OF PROJECT"

while read line; do
    if line contains a; do
         while read line; do
            'if line does not contain b'
               'append the line to output.txt'; fi
         done
     done
     fi
done
```

Perhaps there is an easier way using sed, awk, grep and pipes?

```
'for every document' 'loop through it doing this' ('find the original text between START and END' | >> output.txt)
```

Unfortunately I am poor at bash and ignorant of sed/awk.

The reason for this is that I am assembling a huge text document that is a concatenation of thousands of marked up documents – each of which contains some annotated passages.

Comment: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice right away and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins ASAP. Post some concise, testable sample input and expected output to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python:

```
import re
with open('in.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write('\n'.join(re.findall(r'START OF TEXT(.*?)END OF TEXT', f.read())))
```

This reads the input, searches for all matches that begin and end with the necessary markers, captures the text of interest in a group, joins all those groups on a linefeed, and writes that to the result file.

Comment: tried the code below but I get an unexpected indent error at line 11: With open...
`
import os
import re`
'#walk the directory'
'rootDir = '.''
'for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):'
'    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)'
 '   for fname in fileList:'
  '      print('\t%s' % fname)'
'#second part ' 
'     with open(fname) as infile, open('out.txt', 'a') as out file:'
'         full=infile.read().replace('\n','')'
'      text = ''.join(re.findall(r"START(.+?)END", full))'
'      outfile.write(text)'
'      infile.close()'
'      outfile.close()`

Comment: I tried the code below but I get an unexpected indent error at line 11: With open...

`import re`
`#walk the directory`
`rootDir = '.'`
`for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):`
`    print("Found directory: %s" % dirName)`
`    for fname in fileList:`
`        print("\t%s" % fname)`
`#extract the text from the found file`
`     with open(fname) as infile, open('out.txt', 'a') as outfile:`
`         full=infile.read().replace('\n','')`
`      text = ''.join(re.findall(r"START(.+?)END", full))`
`      outfile.write(text)`
`      infile.close()`
`      outfile.close()`

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I cannot make comments look nice.Here is a paste bin of a properly formatted reply----http://pastebin.com/XzyrQWW0

Comment: I don't know why that  is a indent error. If i 'outdent' the code, then the variable frame does not yet exist and I get that I/O error.

Comment: @aquagremlin - From that pastebin, I don't see a problem near line 11 (`for fname in fileList:`). Check your spacing and tabs.

Comment: I fixed the spacing issue. Unfortunately a random space can hide after a tab. Now the script is saying it cannot find the first file when it goes to open it. I think the problem is the script is running from the topmost directory but when i give the filename to 'open' , it's not there because it's buried in a folder. So i have to construct a pathname for each found file. Or find the pathname from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do with `awk`. You would create a script (I'll call it yank.awk) containing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

/START OF PROJECT/ { capture = 1; next }
/END OF PROJECT/ { capture = 0 }
capture == 1 { print }
```

and then run it like so:

`yank.awk in.txt > output.txt`

Could also do with `sed` and `grep`:

```
sed -ne '/START OF PROJECT/,/END OF PROJECT/p' in.txt | grep -vE '(START|END) OF PROJECT' > output.txt
```

Comment: made your three liner into a bash script, made it executable, put it in  folder with a file named 'one', executed it as        ./yank.awk and got:syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> . <<< /yank.awk
/usr/bin/awk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: You need to provide in.txt and output.txt as redirects like I did above.

Answer (score 0):

(Another Python solution)

You can have `itertools.groupby` group lines together based on a boolean value - just use a global flag to keep track of whether you are in a block or not, and then use `groupby` to group the lines that are in or out of blocks. Then just discard the ones that are not blocks:

```
sample_lines = """
lskdjflsdkjf
sldkjfsdlkjf
START OF TEXT
Asdlkfjlsdkfj
Bsldkjf
Clsdkjf
END OF TEXT
sldkfjlsdkjf
sdlkjfdklsjf
sdlkfjdlskjf
START OF TEXT
Dsdlkfjlsdkfj
Esldkjf
Flsdkjf
END OF TEXT
sldkfjlsdkjf
sdlkjfdklsjf
sdlkfjdlskjf
""".splitlines()

from itertools import groupby

in_block = False
def is_in_block(line):
    global in_block
    if line.startswith("END OF TEXT"):
        in_block = False
    ret = in_block
    if line.startswith("START OF TEXT"):
        in_block = True
    return ret

for lines_are_text,lines in groupby(sample_lines, key=is_in_block):
    if lines_are_text:
        print(list(lines))
```

gives:

```
['Asdlkfjlsdkfj', 'Bsldkjf', 'Clsdkjf']
['Dsdlkfjlsdkfj', 'Esldkjf', 'Flsdkjf']
```

See that first group has the lines that start with A, B, and C, and the second group is made up of those lines starting with D, E, and F.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed as follows:

```
sed -n '/^START OF TEXT/,/^END OF TEXT/{/^\(START\|END\) OF TEXT/!p}' infile
```

or, with extended regular expressions (`-r`):

```
sed -rn '/^START OF TEXT/,/^END OF TEXT/{/^(START|END) OF TEXT/!p}' infile
```

`-n` prevents sed from printing as a default. The rest works as follows:

```
/^START OF TEXT/,/^END OF TEXT/ {  # For lines between these two matches
    /^\(START\|END\) OF TEXT/!p    # If the line does NOT match, print it
}
```

This works with GNU sed and might require some tweaking to run with other seds.

Comment: You really should anchor your expressions, and use the `-r` flag for extended regular expressions to avoid all that escaping. You're probably also assuming GNU sed for regex-based addressing; if so, you should state that you're relying on GNU sed extensions.

Comment: @CodeGnome Point taken about anchoring, I've added that. As for the `-r` flag: it's non-portable, so I didn't use it here; regex-based addressing, on the other hand, is POSIX conform. In my opinion, this is portable as is.

Comment: Your code won't work with BSD sed as provided by OS X. It reports `sed: 1: "/^START OF TEXT/,/^END  ...": extra characters at the end of p command`, so it's probably not as portable as you think. However, `gsed -rn '/^START OF TEXT/,/^END OF TEXT/{/^(START|END)/!p}' /tmp/corpus` works fine. YMMV.

Comment: If you use `p;}` it just prints everything. Like I said earlier, the solution you're using is a good one, but it really is a GNU sed solution AFAICT. I'm not intending to bike-shed here; I would just hate to see you attract downvotes over time when your "portable" solution isn't. Maybe you can refactor it to make it truly portable, but I would personally mark it as GNU sed and move on with life. :) Whatever you decide to do, kudos for posting a sed solution; they're often overlooked.

Comment: @CodeGnome I only was foolish enough to claim portability in comments ;) I'll amend that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the specific solution you need is:

```
awk '/END OF TEXT OF PASSAGE/{f=0} f; /START OF TEXT OF PASSAGE/{f=1}' file
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409469/1745001 for other ways to select text from files.

Comment: trying to take baby steps. I have a folder with a file containing the text and two tags in it. I open a terminal and navigate to that folder. I put that line in terminal and it works! I duplicated the file. Then i put a script in the folder with this code: first line: for z in myfolder/*; second line: do  third line:  awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}' z  fourth line: done; ----I get the error 'can't open file z'. I am trying to iterate through the files and append the found text to an output file.

Comment: In shell you use `"$z"` to access the contents of a variable named `z`. You do not need the loop at all though, just `awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}' myfolder/*`. btw there are no folders in UNIX, they're called directories.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Perl's Flip-Flop Operator to Print Text Between Markers

Given a corpus like:

```
START OF TEXT OF PASSAGE 1
foo
END OF TEXT OF PASSAGE 1

START OF TEXT OF PASSAGE 2
bar
END OF TEXT OF PASSAGE 2
```

you can use the Perl flip-flop operator to process within a range of lines. For example, from the shell prompt:

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/^START OF TEXT/ ... /^END OF TEXT/) {
               next if /^(?:START|END)/;
               print;
            }' /tmp/corpus
foo
bar
```

Basically, this short Perl script loops through your input. When it finds your start and end tags, it throws away the tags themselves and prints everything else in between.

### Usage Notes

The line breaks between passages in the corpus are for readability. It doesn't matter if your real corpus has no line breaks between passages, so long as the text markers always start at the beginning of the line as shown in your original post. If that assumption doesn't hold true, then you will need to adjust the regular expressions used to identify the start and end of your passages.

You can pass multiple files to the Perl script. Again, it makes no practical difference as long as you don't exceed the length limit of your shell.

If you want the final output to go to somewhere other than standard output, just use shell redirection. For example:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^START OF TEXT/ ... /^END OF TEXT/) {
               next if /^(?:START|END)/;
               print;
          }' /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 /tmp/file3 > /tmp/output
```