# How to grep/sed/awk and get next couple of lines until a certain pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I am having difficulty grabbing a few lines from text file. For instance say I have the following text in a file:

```
A I have a cat
B I have a dog
C I have a mouse
X I have a monkey
B I have a rat
T I have a cat
C I have a deer
X I have a turkey
```

I am trying to find all lines that contain the word "cat" and if the sentence has an "A" as the first letter, I'd like to get the next few lines (including the line that matched the pattern "cat") until I encounter the letter "X" as the first letter of a line.

So for instance, the above text file should print out:

```
A I have a cat
B I have a dog
C I have a mouse
```

(prints out until it sees the X)

Note: The line "T I have a cat" should not match because even though it has cat it does not start with the letter "A"

I tried searching for help but could not find anything on printing out lines until a certain pattern is matched. The closest I could find was

`awk '/cat/ {for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}' filename`

but that prints out a certain number of lines. I want it to print out until it sees the next pattern which is an "X"

Comment: If you're ever considering using getline then please read http://awk.info/?tip/getline so you understand why that's almost always the wrong approach and how to implement it robustly in those rare occasions when it is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @EdMorton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^X/{f=0} /^A.*cat/{f=1} f' file
A I have a cat
B I have a dog
C I have a mouse
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18409469/1745001.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` instead of `awk`:

```
$ sed -n '/^A.* cat/,/^X/{/^X/d;p;}' data
A I have a cat
B I have a dog
C I have a mouse
$
```

- `-n` — do not print by default,
- `/^A.* cat/` — from a line starting with `A` and containing `cat` after a space (adjust to suit definitions of `cat`; it would pick up `A I visited the catacombs`, for example),
- `/^X/` — up to a line starting with `X`,
- `{/^X/d;` — delete any line (the only line) starting with `X`, and move on to process the next line,
- `p;}` — print the line.

As shown, it will work with BSD `sed` and GNU `sed`; GNU `sed` does not require the final semicolon.

Comment: Here is another `sed` way to selective print: `sed -n '/^A.*cat/,/^X/{/^X/!p}' file`