# reading multiple lines based on an IF condition

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a very big file that contains these data :

```
qry> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/2-OutputPlatesTest/20150615_053914.455_0_Front.Frontview.png
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_055509.656_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_083627.005_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_054920.969_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)

qry> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/2-OutputPlatesTest/20150615_054239.612_0_Front.Frontview.png
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_060212.816_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_091652.202_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_081529.893_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_061203.680_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%


qry> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/2-OutputPlatesTest/20150615_054241.898_0_Front.Frontview.png
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_055047.746_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_061414.016_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_054643.282_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_090622.440_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_083110.342_0_Front.Frontview.png       (99%)
```

What I would like to read is just the qry> line and the first line that comes after it , i don't know how to do it using awk or sed or bash

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18409469/1745001

Answer (score 2):

You could get that line and the line after it with GNU `grep` with the `-A` flag

```
grep -A1 'qry>' <filename>
```

which will match the line containing `qry>` and the `-A` flag will tell it to also grab 1 line after the match as well.

Or you could do it more POSIX-ly with `sed` like:

```
sed -n '/qry>/ {p;n;p;}' <filename>
```

Here's how that works:

- `-n` tells `sed` not to print lines unless we explicitly do it
- `/qry>/` matches lines that contain that string
- `{p;n;p;}` prints the current line (the one matching `qry>`), go to the `n`ext line, then print that one too

To do it in pure bash so you can operate on the lines more easily you could do it like so

```
while read -r cur; do
    if [[ "$cur" =~ 'qry>' ]]; then
        read -r result
        # Do something here with the query in $cur and the first line in $result
        printf "query line: %s\nnext line: %s\n" "$cur" "$result"
    fi
done < your_input_file
```

Comment: sed can be more succinct. `sed '/qry>/!d;N' file`

Comment: @M.Cesar what is "this" that you want to read?  Do you want to get the full output of all the lines together as a single string in your variable, or did you want to get each pair in a variable to operate on separately?

Comment: each pair to operate separately

Comment: @M.Cesar see my update for a bash version that will give you each line in a variable that you can operate on

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} flag{print;flag=0} /qry>/{print;flag=1}' <filename>
```