# How use BSD / OS X sed to remove / delete X Lines after match

Tags: bash, shell, sed, bsd

This questions been asked a number of times but the answers given are ALL GNU sed specific.

`sed -i '' "/${FIND}/,+2d" "$FILE"`

Gives a "expected context address" error.

Please could someone give me an example of how to use BSD sed to delete X lines including the match and another X lines excluding the match?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this is simply not a job for sed, it's  job for awk.

```
$ seq 5 | awk '/3/{c=2} !(c&&c--)'
1
2
5
```

Just set the variable `c` to however many lines you want to skip.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409469/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sed` editing script (run with `-n`) will emulate what GNU `sed` `/^pattern/,+2d` does:

```
/^pattern/{
    n
    n
    d
}

p
```

When matching `/^pattern/`, it will read the next two lines of input, and then discard everything (restarting the cycle). When the pattern doesn't match, the line is printed.