# Print from Nth match to Mth match

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

How do I print from the nth match to the mth match in a file?

For example

```
>1
dfgsdrhsdtrh
>2
zdfrgsdh
>3
zdsfgadrh
>4
sdtrh
>5
drh
```

If I want the 2nd to the 4th match to the regexp '^>', including the Nth match and up to but not including the M+1th match. Yielding, for example:

```
>2
zdfrgsdh
>3
zdsfgadrh
>4
sdtrh
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/258523 for the answer to this and many other similar requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnu-awk you can use this `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='>' -v ORS='>' 'BEGIN{printf ">"} NR>5{exit} NR>2 && NR<=5' file
>2
zdfrgsdh
>3
zdsfgadrh
>4
sdtrh
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Is there a way to get it to quit after the last match instead of continuing to search through the file?

Comment: Yes sure that can be done. See edited answer for exiting once record is passed.

Comment: It still prints the last field separator '>' at the end. I can just pipe it through 'head -n-1' though...

Comment: Actually with your input data it doesn't print `>` at the end for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `\K` construct if supported. If not, just remove the `\K` and put capture
parenthesis around what comes after it.

```
 #  (?m)(?:^>.*\r?\n(?:^(?!>).*\r?\n)*){1}\K(?:^>.*\r?\n(?:^(?!>).*\r?\n)*){3}

 (?m)                    # MULTI_LINE mode

 (?:                     # 0 to N-1
      ^ > .* \r? \n 
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?! > )
           .* \r? \n 
      )*
 ){1}                    # Do N-1 times

 \K                      # Disgard previous from match

 (?:                     # N to M+1
      ^ > .* \r? \n 
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?! > )
           .* \r? \n 
      )*
 ){3}                    # Do M+1-N times
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 18 , len 40 ) 
>2
zdfrgsdh
>3
zdsfgadrh
>4
sdtrh
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS=">" '$1>=2 && $1<=4 {$0=RS$0;gsub(/\n$/,"");print}' file
>2
zdfrgsdh
>3
zdsfgadrh
>4
sdtrh
```

It prints record from `>2` to  `>4`