# A way to get around next in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have to print the next line if the previous line matches a condition.

file `a.dat` with below contents

```
1
2
3
1
2
1
```

`if $1 matches 3 then print 1(next line)`. I tried it with below awk statement

```
awk ' { if($1=="3") { {next} {print $1} } }' a.dat
```

but it didn't work. When i was looking for it i understood that when awk encounters a `next` no further rules are executed for the current record, hence i got an empty result. Is there a way to get around this with `next` itself using awk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear when you say "matches 3" if you mean contains 3 or is numerically equal to 3 or is string equal to 3 or something else or if you want to print every line that follows a 3 or just the first or if you want to print a line containing 3 if the previous line was 3 or skip until you reach a non-3 but the general approach would be based on:

```
awk 'f{print; f=0} $0==3{f=1}' file
```

or even:

```
awk 'f&&f--; $0==3{f=1}' file
```

The variable `f` is commonly used to mean `found`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for how to generally print lines after matches with awk.

Comment: and I thought `f` was for `flag` `:P`

Comment: 3 is numeric and i would like to print the next line..  awk 'f{print; f=0} $0==3{f=1}' file  was the one i was looking for.. thanks.. :)

Comment: @jaypalsingh no, a flag is what it is, not what it means. Down that path would lie `v` for `variable`, though I'm as guilty as anyone else of using `a` for `array` but for some reason my sensibilities don't scream over that one as long as it's glaringly obvious what it's being used for in a tiny script :-).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/bbbbb/{a=1;next}a{print;a=0}' File
```

Pattern being searched for is `bbbbb`. If pattern found, set variable `a to 1`. Goto next record. If `a` is 1, print the record and unset `a`. This will print the next line for all the lines matching the `pattern`.

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat File
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
AMD$ awk '/bbbbb/{a=1;next}a{print;a=0}' File
ccccc
ccccc
```

Comment: ++ for **not** using `getline` (see [this](http://awk.info/?tip/getline) for why not). I would write it as `awk 'p{print; p=0}/3/{p=1}' file`

Comment: Why use `if(a)` inside an unconditional block, rather than `a{...`?

Answer (score 0):

This will print the next line if pattern is true:

```
awk '_-->0;$1==3{_=1}' file
4
```

some more readable..

```
awk 'f-->0;$1==3{f=1}' file
```

or as Ed suggested.

```
awk 'f&&f--;$1==3{f=1}' file
```

---

Another variation

```
awk '/^3$/{f=1;next} f-->0' file
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that naming a variable `_` has a significant negative impact on the readability. Why would you do that? It's arguably the second-worst possible choice of variable name, right behind naming the variable with double negatives (`not_un_found=1`). I also wouldn't use an unguarded `f-->0` in case the input file is so huge that the variable value wraps back around to positive - hence the `f&&f--` guard to stop decrementing at zero.

Comment: @EdMorton It was was just for fun.  Fixed it.

Comment: Sounds good, we don't want anyone confusing awk with the p-word ;-).