# how to print file from the match string until EOF

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, solaris

the following command print the file until the match WORD

```
 awk '1;/WORD/{exit}' file
```

but how to print the file from the string WORD until the end of file not include the string WORD?

Comment: The fantastic answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/258523) includes an answer to your question.

Comment: That would not print until the string WORD, it would print until the end of the line that contains the string WORD. Post some sample input and expected output and place "WORD" in the middle of a line if that's possible in your real input. Also consider how you would want NEWORDER treated if it occurred mid-file - does the WORD in the middle of that match your string or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Etan Reisner says in a comment, there is a nice cookbook of range patterns in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/258523). But the simplest way to match from a pattern to the end of a file is:

```
awk '/WORD/,0' file
```

In order to print from the line following the line containing a pattern, we could instead do this:

```
awk 'found,0;/WORD/{found=1}' file
```

To also print the part of the first line which matches WORD following WORD, it is only necessary to modify the last action, but it's convenient to replace the regular expression with an explicit call to `match` in order to set RSTART and RLENGTH:

```
awk 'found,0;match($0,/WORD/){found=1;print substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH}'
```

Range patterns have the form *expression***,***expression*, and the meaning is to match from the first line which matches the first expression to the first line which matches the last expression, inclusively. The range is repeated until the file is fully processed.

In these examples, the second expression always evaluates to 0 (false), so the range never terminates and all lines are matched once the pattern succeeds.

Similarly, another way to solve the "print all lines *until* a pattern" would be the following, although it is less efficient because it reads the entire file:

```
awk 'NR==1,/WORD/' file
```

Also, if the goal is to print up to only the instance of the pattern (as opposed to the complete line containing th pattern, we could produce a simple modification of the original program:

```
awk 'match($0, /WORD/){print(sub($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH)); exit}1'
```

Comment: That would include the record containing "WORD", the OP wants to exclude it.

Comment: so how to fix that so it will not print the WORD?

Answer (score 1):

This MIGHT be what you want:

```
$ cat file                                 
As market-days are wearing late,
And folk begin WORD to tak the gate;
While we sit bousin, at the nappy,
And gettin fou and unco happy,

$ awk '!f && sub(/.*WORD/,""){f=1} f' file
 to tak the gate;
While we sit bousin, at the nappy,
And gettin fou and unco happy,
```

Comment: Yeah, but if WORD appears twice in the line? :)

Comment: Then this may or may not do what he wants just like if WORD appeared a second time anywhere else in the file or if it appeared mid-word or .... The OP hasn't put a lot of thought into his requirements or if he has he hasn't told us about them yet! It was a good excuse to quote some Burns either way though :-).

Comment: Absolutely true, the problem is underspecified. But "print from the string WORD" needs to be interpreted very loosely to generate "print from the last occurrence of WORD in the first line containing WORD".

Comment: True but I suspect his real input has WORD on it's own on a line and I don't want to put much thought/effort into this until we see some decent requirements and sample input/output. Hopefully this will get the OP thinking...

Comment: I was looking at a short solution, but it gives  `WORD` at the end.  Do you have any idea on how to fix it:  `awk -v RS="WORD" 'NR>1' ORS="WORD"` It works if there are only one pattern in the file and we remove the `ORS`

Comment: Change it to `awk -v RS="WORD" -v ORS= 'NR>1' file`. You need to set ORS to null to stop it from appending a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

If text have only one `pattern`, this `gnu awk` (gnu due to the RS) will work:

```
awk -v RS="WORD" 'NR>1' file
```

It will work as Eds solution, start with first data after `WORD` and print the rest of the line and all next line to the `EOF`

---

This will print the next line after the `WORD` is found and until  `EOF`
If you need data on the same line after `WORD` look at Eds answer.

```
awk 'f;/WORD/{f=1}' file
```

---

Example, pattern `four`

```
cat file
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
10 ten
```

```
awk 'f;/four/ {f=1}' file
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
10 ten
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1,/WORD/{/WORD/!d;s//\n/;D}' file
```

This deletes all the lines up until WORD and then replaces WORD by a newline and delete up until and including the newline. The remaining file is printed as normal.