# how to understand this nawk command

Tags: awk, nawk

How to understand the following awk command?

```
nawk 'a-- >= 0; /datamart_extractrelations_static/ {a = 30}' app.log
```

Given a awk program has a format of:

```
pattern { action }
```

What is 'a-- >= 0' do? when does this operation get executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is the same as:

```
nawk 'a-- >= 0 {print}; /datamart_extractrelations_static/ {a = 30}' app.log
```

If `a-- >= 0` `awk` will print the current line since `print` is the default action in `awk` which will be executed if no action was specified.

As a result, the command will print the 30ths line after a line that contains the pattern `datamart_extractrelations_static`

To better understand this, you can simply try the following command:

```
awk '1' input
```

Since `1` will always evaluate to `true` and the default action is `print` `awk` prints every line of input unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Someone didn't quite get the idiom right for printing 30 lines after datamart_extractrelations_static is found in the input. See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) and look specifically at idiom e there "Print the N records after some pattern" for the correct code. The code you posted is missing the leading test on `a` (who names a **count** variable `a`???) to make sure the var doesn't keep decrementing below zero for a huge file and eventually wrap around and appear positive again.

Comment: Wow. this is phenominal! Thanks for sharing.