# Grep a pattern and also print the header of the file

Tags: linux, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file that contains information like the following:

```
header info line 1 
header info line 2
header info line 3
   ....
process: 1
   info 1
   info 2
   info 3

process: 2
   info 1
   info 2
   info 3

process: 3
   info 1
   info 2
   info 3
```

What I want to do is grep for one of the process lines (e.x "process: 2") then delete the other process while keeping the header information. What I know is the number of lines after the "process: #" (Lets just use 3 for this example). What I don't know is how many process numbers there are. What I was trying was:

```
 grep "process: 2" -A 3 file.txt
```

However I lose the header information. I want to keep the header info but get rid of all the other process info. I feel like I can do this with an egrep but I'm not sure how.

My desired output is the following:

```
header info line 1
header info line 2
header info line 3
   ....
process: 2
   info 1
   info 2
   info 3
```

Comment: I'll make an edit sorry about that.

Comment: Is there any pattern to what the header lines look like?  Is that pattern distinct from the rest of the lines in the file?

Comment: Yes the header lines will be distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk -v N=3 -v header=4 '/process: 2/{c=N+1} NR<=header || c&&c--;' file
header info line 1 
header info line 2
header info line 3
   ....
process: 2
   info 1
   info 2
   info 3
```

This uses [printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1983854) together with a check on the lines on the header.

#### Explanation

- `-v N=3 -v header=4` provide the amount of lines the header has (`header`) and how many lines after the match should be printed (`N`).
- `/process: 2/{c=N+1}` when `process: 2` line is seen, set the variable `c` (from counter).
- `c&&c--` evaluate `c`. If its value is bigger than `0`, it evaluates as True, so that the line is printed. Also, decrement the value so that just `N` lines are printed.
- `NR<=header` if the line number is equal or lower than the given value `header`, it evaluates to True and the line is printed.

Comment: @pdm see my update with a proper Explanation. It is basically a way to keep track how many lines after the match have been printed so far.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. This clears up everything.

Answer (score 1):

sed's nice too

```
sed -n '1,4p; /^process: 2$/ {N;N;N;p;q}' file.txt
```

That will print the first 4 lines, and when we see the desired pattern, read the next 3 lines, print and quit.

Answer (score 0):

head -1 file; grep something file