# Sed line match plus line below

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I can find my lines with this pattern, but in some case the info is on the line after the match. How can I also get the line following my match line?

```
sed -n '/SQL3227W  Record token/p' /log/PLAN_2015-08-16*.MSG >ERRORS.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this looks like a job for `grep`:

```
grep -A 1 'SQL3227W  Record token' /log/PLAN_2015-08-16*.MSG >ERRORS.txt
```

(`-A 1` means to print an additional **1** line **A**fter the match).

Secondly, if you're using GNU `sed`, you can use a second address of `+1` thus:

```
sed -n '/SQL3227W  Record token/,+1p' /log/PLAN_2015-08-16*.MSG >ERRORS.txt
```

Otherwise, (if you really must use non-Gnu `sed`), then each time you match, append the following line to your pattern space.  Delete the first line, before continuing loop (in case the second line is also a match).

Untested code:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
/SQL3227W  Record token/{
N
P
D
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything even slightly more interesting just use awk:

```
awk '/SQL3227W  Record token/{c=2} c&&c--' file
```

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern) for other related idioms.