# How to use sed to get contents between two two lines, but the two matched lines are escaped

Tags: bash, sed

I am currently playing with sed to get contents between two lines. I got a nice tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-print-only-matching-lines-command/

In this tutorial, I found:

```
sed -n -e '/regexpA/,/regexpB/p' input.file
```

The command above will print also the lines matched `regexpA` and `regexpB`, but I would want to escape these two line, say these two matched lines would not print to STDOUT, is there any beautiful solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly what you need: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
sed '1,/regexpA/d;/regexpB/,$d' input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, just use awk:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
e

$ awk '/b/{f=1} f; /d/{f=0}' file
b
c
d

$ awk 'f; /b/{f=1} /d/{f=0}' file
c
d

$ awk '/b/{f=1} /d/{f=0} f' file
b
c

$ awk '/d/{f=0} f; /b/{f=1}' file
c
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for other common awk range searching idioms.

Comment: Nice! This looks like ping pong! :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/regexpA/,/regexpB/!d;//d' file
```

Delete all lines before and after `regexpA` and `regexpB` and then delete lines which match `regexpA` and `regexpB`.