# SED: delete lines after pattern match while skipping a few lines, then delete the pattern line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Let's say I want to delete some lines after the pattern while skipping some lines in-between, and then delete the line with the pattern itself. I can do this using the following two commands:

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/{n;n;n;n;n;n;N;N;N;N;d}' file  # match pattern, skip 5 lines, then delete 5 consecutive lines
sed -i /PATTERN/d file  # delete line with pattern
```

But I want to do this in a single command. The problem here is obvious as the pattern change affects both expressions so the change must be specified in a single expression. Is there a way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

Example input:

```
...
ifeq ($(ose),)
    dh_installdocs \
        $(archdir)/UserManual*.pdf $(archdir)/VirtualBox*.chm \
        $(addprefix $(archdir)/, LICENSE)
    rm $(addprefix $(archdir)/,UserManual*.pdf VirtualBox*.chm \
        LICENSE)
else
    dh_installdocs \
        $(archdir)/UserManual*.pdf
    rm $(addprefix $(archdir)/,UserManual*.pdf)
endif
...
```

Example output:

```
...
    dh_installdocs \
        $(archdir)/UserManual*.pdf $(archdir)/VirtualBox*.chm \
        $(addprefix $(archdir)/, LICENSE)
    rm $(addprefix $(archdir)/,UserManual*.pdf VirtualBox*.chm \
        LICENSE)
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The example file can be obtained here: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.4/VirtualBox-5.0.4.tar.bz2 (*debian/rules*)

Comment: Does it have to be `sed` and a single command? Can you give an example input and output for testing? But first thought would - if you're doing keyed on the same pattern, doesn't that mean you're deleting then skipping?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a one line command, preferably sed. If sed isn't an option then maybe others will do (I haven't looked for an answer outside of sed). I will update the initial post with an example.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted?

Comment: There was an answer before suggesting to use `x;` after `{`. This partially works as it deletes everything from the line with the matching pattern while leaving a blank line. Is there a way to remove the whole line?

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong with my question so I can fix it. I'm always trying to properly formulate my questions before posting.

Comment: Any ideas how can I do this with `sed`? The answers below are too complex for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
sed '/($(ose),)/,/^endif/{/($(ose),)/d;/^else/,/^endif/d}' file
```

Output:

```
...
    dh_installdocs \
        $(archdir)/UserManual*.pdf $(archdir)/VirtualBox*.chm \
        $(addprefix $(archdir)/, LICENSE)
    rm $(addprefix $(archdir)/,UserManual*.pdf VirtualBox*.chm \
        LICENSE)
...
```

Add option `-i` to edit "in place".

Comment: Now shoot me. Such an simple and clever workaround. Why didn't I think of this before? THANK YOU countless times!!

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk 's&&s--{print;next} d&&d--{next} /pattern/{d=5;s=5;next} 1'
```

set s for skip and d for delete, using Ed Morton's [smart counters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1435869)

For your pattern you need to escape special chars

```
awk 's&&s--{print;next} d&&d--{next} /\(\$\(ose\),\)/{d=5;s=5;next} 1'
```

Comment: How can I use `($(ose),)` as the pattern?

Comment: Is it literal "($(ose),)"? Use the quoted value as a variable and change `/patttern/` to $0~var

Comment: Yes, it's literal as you can see in the example. Using a variable requires an extra line so it defeats the purpose. Anyway, I wasn't able to get it working.

Comment: setting the var is for convenience and can be done with awk `-v` option, if you like you can embed the pattern by escaping `$ ( )` as in `/\(\$\(ose\),\)/`

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be `sed` I would offer that `perl` can work in "sed mode" and use regular expressions along with some more complex scripting logic.

E.g. a for loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   if ( m/ifeq\ \(\$\(ose\)\,\)/ ) {

       print "". <DATA> for 1..5;
       <DATA> for ( 1..5 );
   }
   else { print };
}

__DATA__
...
ifeq ($(ose),)
    dh_installdocs \
        $(archdir)/UserManual*.pdf $(archdir)/VirtualBox*.chm \
        $(addprefix $(archdir)/, LICENSE)
    rm $(addprefix $(archdir)/,UserManual*.pdf VirtualBox*.chm \
        LICENSE)
else
    dh_installdocs \
        $(archdir)/UserManual*.pdf
    rm $(addprefix $(archdir)/,UserManual*.pdf)
endif
...
```

Which you could do 'inline' like sed:

```
perl -i -ne 'if ( m/ifeq\ \(\$\(ose\)\,\)/ ) { print "". <> for 1..5; <> for ( 1..5 );} else {print}'
```

Alternatively, you can use perl's "range operator" to detect if you're between two patterns. That depends rather more on the rest of your file though (I assume 'else' ... 'endif' isn't exactly uncommon).

Comment: Does it mean that `sed` cannot be used for this?

Comment: I don't know. `sed` can do a lot of stuff, but I started using `perl` 15 years ago when I started hitting the limits of "shell tools" and haven't really looked back.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying your command: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "else print
"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: Might need the braces then - sorry, can't test that bit. Edited

Comment: Unfortunately, the change you made now doubles every line in the file for some reason.

Comment: OK. Remove everything after the else then:) (amended again)

Comment: Thinking about it, that is probably something we would want to use -ne

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do it using awk:

```
awk '/ifeq/ { n = 6; next } n && !--n { c = 1 } c && c++ < 6 { next }1' file
```

It's a bit tricky looking but the logic is as follows:

- When the pattern `/ifeq/` matches, set the variable `n` to 6 and skip the line
- `n && !--n` is only true when `n` is 1 (it is written this way so that `n` is only decremented until it reaches 0)
- When `c` has been set, skip each line until `c` reaches 6
- `1` at the end means that any line that has not been skipped is printed (the default action is
  `{ print }`.

Comment: This seems to work but how can I save the results to a file? Adding `-i` doesn't work.

Comment: The standard way to do that is to redirect to a temporary file then overwrite the original: `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: I already tried redirecting the output to a different file but awk hangs when I do that (i.e. waits for input).

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error to me. Using the code in my answer and assuming that the file is called `file`, it would be: `awk '/ifeq/ { n = 6; next } n && !--n { c = 1 } c && c++ < 6 { next }1' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: This worked, however, the resulting file is not correct. Several lines are missing across the file.

Comment: You probably need to change `/ifeq/` to be more specific (it was just an example of a pattern which works for the input you showed). If the string you're trying to match is `($(ose),)`, then  you could use `/\(\$\(ose\),\)/` as your pattern (i.e. escape the parentheses and $).