# With Awk and Grep i need to print some lines

Tags: bash, perl, awk, grep

I am fresher in writing perl scripts,so i am asking this as question or support on this, below is the code

```
start pattern1

line1
Matching pattern can be here
line2
Matching Pattern can be here
line3
line4
...
end pattern1
.
start pattern1
line1
line2
start pattern1

start pattern1
line1
Matching pattern can be here
line2
start pattern1
```

so from perl i need to grep the lines between start pattern1 ... end pattern1,
for this i am using awk command to grep

```
 $cmd = q(awk '/start pattern1/,end pattern1 /' x.file );
 $n1 = system($cmd);
```

For this output works fine,Below is the output,

```
start pattern1
line1
**Matching pattern can be here**
line2
**Matching Pattern can be here**
...
end pattern1
```

But in the files i have 1000 of lines like this, so i need to grep those lines which have Matching pattern. i.e i need to grep only those starting pattern lines to ending pattern lines has matching pattern

For this i tried

```
 $cmd = q(awk '/start pattern1/,end pattern1 /' x.file | grep  '$n2\|line4');
 $n1 = system($cmd);
```

But when i use the above command i don't see any output
Here $n2 contains some pattern which is grepped from another file.

if i use direct matched patternin place of $n2 it works fine, why cant i use $n2 here?

Note:i am using this in perl script

From the Awk command i get all the lines between start pattern1...end pattern1,But i have 1000 of such prints, so i need the bunch of the lines of start pattern1 to end pattern1 of thos which get matched with the matching pattern

The expected output when i do is,

```
start pattern1
line1
Matching pattern can be here
line2
Matching Pattern can be here
line3
line4
...
end pattern1 

 start pattern1
    line1
    Matching pattern can be here
    line2
    start pattern1
```

Comment: could you please mention clear expected output along with method of getting it and let us know then?

Comment: From the Awk command i get all the lines between start pattern1...end pattern1,But i have 1000 of such prints, so i need the bunch of the lines of start pattern1 to end pattern1 of thos which get matched with the matching pattern

Ex:


  my file has like the below linesstart pattern1
line1
Matching pattern can be here
line2
Matching Pattern can be here
line3
line4
...
end pattern1
.
start pattern1
line1
line2
start pattern1

start pattern1
line1
Matching pattern can be here
line2
start pattern1

Comment: If you're trying to do this from within a perl script then there is no need to involve awk or grep. Just use built-in perl functionality.

Comment: @RamCharan, comments are NOT meant for explanation of question, please update your question with proper details and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh  sorry for that i have updated this with expected details. Thanks for bringing up that.

Comment: @Tom Fenech can you help me how to call the builr in function]

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is that `q()` doesn't interpolate variables, but this whole code is terrible and should be thrown away.

Comment: but from those grepping it makes my work easier and reduces a lot of time @melpomene

Comment: @RamCharan if you need to update a perl script, you need to learn perl. Calling system() from any language just because you don't know the syntax is bad practice.

Comment: awk | grep is an anti-pattern.  Invoking awk inside perl is an anti-pattern.  Invoking awk piped to grep inside perl is anti-matter and may lead to the destruction of the known universe.

Comment: It's amazing how often some version of this question pops up. I think I've near-answered it a few times, lol. Search the site, man. :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976613/search-for-text-between-two-patterns-with-multiple-lines-in-between)'s the first hit I found.  Check the manuals for [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) & [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) and definitely for [`perl`](https://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html).

Comment: "Invoking awk piped to grep inside perl is anti-matter and may lead to the destruction of the known universe." - [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell), you are my new favorite person. :)

Comment: "Invoking awk piped to grep inside perl..." - **William Pursell**, and wrap all into a Python script for good measure.

Comment: @PaulHodges Wow!  That's high praise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No need to summon awk from within perl since perl is much more powerful than awk.

It's not clear to me whether you want *every* line between `start pattern1` and `end pattern1` if there is at least one match inside, or *just* the matching lines.

If every line between start and end if match:

```
my @blocks = join("",<>)=~/start pattern1\s*(.*?)end pattern1/gsi;
print grep /matching pattern/i, @blocks;
```

If every line INCLUDING start|end pattern1:

```
my @blocks = join("",<>)=~/(start pattern1.*?end pattern1\s*)/gsi;
```

If just lines with /matching pattern/ between start and end:

```
print grep { /start pattern1/i../end pattern1/i and /matching pattern/i } <>;
```

Put that inside a file program.pl and run:

```
perl program.pl inputfile > outputfile
```

Some explanation might be needed: `join("",<>)` returns the whole inputfile as one multi-line string. The `/gsi` modifiers means: `g` matches globally so that the `@block` array will contain what is matched by the parentheses, one array element for each match (without `g` the `@block` array would just get the first block of lines), `s` means that `.` also matches newline characters which it otherwise wouldn't and `i` matches by ignoring case (sees no difference between a-z and A-Z letters). The question mark in `.*?` means no-greedy matching of every character, that is, match until the *next* `end pattern1` and not the last. The `<>` returns the lines of `inputfile` (args after `perl program.pl`) as an array of strings. The `..` is the flip-flop operator which is true after the left side becomes true and false after the right side becomes true and stays false until the left side is true again and so on.

Comment: Thanks Kjetil for the info that was so helpful, and also 1 more query is instead of passing input file from command line can we program that in the above code ??

Comment: @RCV → Yes, just add `open my $fh, "filename.txt" or die;` as the first line. And then replace `<>` with `<$fh>`. (*fh* is short for filehandle)