# Extract column after pattern from file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a sample file which looks like this:

```
5    6    7    8
55   66   77   88

A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4
2    4    6    8
3    8    12   16

E    F    G    H
11   22   33   44
and so on...
```

I would like to enter a command in a bash script or just in a bash terminal to extract one of the columns independently of the others. For instance, I would like to do something like a grep/awk command with the pattern=C and get the following output:

```
C
3
6
12
```

How can I extract a specific column independent of the others and also put a # of lines to extract after the pattern so that I don't get the above column with the 7's or the G column in my output?

Comment: I have tried 'grep -A 3 "C" filename' which gives the desired rows after the pattern but it gives all the columns.

Comment: You should post a subset of relevant data instead of `some stuff .... ` as that can change the dynamics of the answer. Also, while you contemplate doing that, I would recommend going through this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/970195) to try something yourself first.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: I've made the changes. I have seen the answer that you linked to. I played around with those tools for a while but couldn't get the column part to work. This is why I thought an 'awk' command would work but couldn't find how to specify a column. Thank you for your comment and help.

Comment: @ghoti thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always 3 records after the found term:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i=="C") col=i}} col>0 && rcount<=3 {print $col; rcount++}' test
```

This will look at each field in your record and if it finds a "C", it will capture the column number `i`. If the column number is greater than 0 then it will print the contents of the column. It counts up to 3 records and then stops printing.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I have a follow up question though. I would like to be able to specify the pattern and the # of records afterward in the command if I make it a script how can I accomplish that? I've tried replacing "C" with $2 and rcount<=3 with recount<=$3 but they don't seem to be recognized. I think they are being interpreted literally as $2 and $3 instead of the second and third arguments in the command.

Comment: You have to sort of "Send" the variable into the awk script from your bash/sh/csh/whatevs scripts. The way to do this is with awk's `-v` flag:  `awk -v awkvar=$bashvar -v awkvar2=$bashvar2 '{print awkvar, awkvar2}`

Comment: @jaypalsingh That's assuming that the column number is known, which it isn't. Furthermore, your variable isn't being used in your script, but I assume that the `3` should be subbed with `num`.

Comment: wrt `You have to sort of "Send" the variable into the awk script` - that makes it sound complicated when it isn't. You have to initialize your awk variables with the values of your shell variables or with constant values, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
!prevNF { delete f; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) f[$i] = i }
NF && (tgt in f) { print $(f[tgt]) }
{ prevNF = NF }

$ awk -v tgt=C -f tst.awk file
C
3
6
12

$ awk -v tgt=F -f tst.awk file
F
22
```