# Grep a matched line includes below and another matched line includes above

Tags: bash, grep, line

I would like to print a matched line include one line below and another matched line include above.

Here is my file:

```
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_1" ;
  dtu_inst_d[19] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U1970/Y (INVX0_RVT)                             0.03       0.03 r
  U509/Y (AND2X1_RVT)                             0.08       0.11 r
  U1845/Y (NAND3X2_RVT)                           0.13       0.24 f
  U1866/Y (INVX0_RVT)                             0.07       0.31 r
  U482/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)                            0.07       0.39 f
  U1634/Y (NAND2X2_RVT)                           0.13       0.51 r
  U480/Y (AO222X1_RVT)                            0.12       0.63 r
  U1653/Y (AO22X2_RVT)                            0.11       0.74 r
  U1652/Y (DELLN1X2_RVT)                          0.27       1.01 r
  U363/Y (AND4X1_RVT)                             0.11       1.12 r
  ifu_exu_muldivop_d[3] (out)                     0.00       1.12 r
critical voltage 1.00838
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)


  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[21]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: ifu_exu_wen_d
               (output port)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_2" ;
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 r
  U1985/Y (INVX0_RVT)                             0.04       0.04 f
  U1872/Y (AND2X1_RVT)                            0.10       0.14 f
  U1847/Y (IBUFFX2_RVT)                           0.11       0.25 r
  U1846/Y (INVX0_RVT)                             0.06       0.31 f
  U439/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)                            0.09       0.39 r
  U438/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)                            0.09       0.48 f
  U1119/Y (INVX1_RVT)                             0.07       0.55 r
  U1120/Y (INVX1_RVT)                             0.04       0.59 f
  U622/Y (INVX0_RVT)                              0.05       0.64 r
  U329/Y (NAND4X0_RVT)                            0.06       0.70 f
  U325/Y (AO221X1_RVT)                            0.16       0.86 f
  U908/Y (AO21X2_RVT)                             0.12       0.99 f
  U1856/Y (AO21X2_RVT)                            0.12       1.11 f
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.11 f
critical voltage 1.00275
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)


  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[22]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: ifu_exu_wen_d
               (output port)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_3" ;
  dtu_inst_d[22] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U584/Y (NBUFFX2_RVT)                            0.06       0.06 f
  U1872/Y (AND2X1_RVT)                            0.08       0.14 f
  U1847/Y (IBUFFX2_RVT)                           0.11       0.25 r
  U1846/Y (INVX0_RVT)                             0.06       0.31 f
  U439/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)                            0.09       0.39 r
  U438/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)                            0.09       0.48 f
  U1119/Y (INVX1_RVT)                             0.07       0.55 r
  U1120/Y (INVX1_RVT)                             0.04       0.59 f
  U622/Y (INVX0_RVT)                              0.05       0.64 r
  U329/Y (NAND4X0_RVT)                            0.06       0.70 f
  U325/Y (AO221X1_RVT)                            0.16       0.86 f
  U908/Y (AO21X2_RVT)                             0.12       0.99 f
  U1856/Y (AO21X2_RVT)                            0.12       1.10 f
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.10 f
critical voltage 1.00174
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)
```

Output should be:

```
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_1" ;
  dtu_inst_d[19] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_muldivop_d[3] (out)                     0.00       1.12 r
critical voltage 1.00838
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_2" ;
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 r
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.11 f
critical voltage 1.00275
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_3" ;
  dtu_inst_d[22] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.10 f
critical voltage 1.00174
```

I know grep is a tool for this.

```
grep -A 1 name file.txt
```

This prints a matched line including below

```
grep -B 1 critical file.txt
```

This prints another matched line including above.

But, I don't know how to combine two. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I think you would be better of if you could provide a minimum example.

Comment: grep -C 1 name file.txt

Comment: @KeithTyler: from a [deleted comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059733/grep-a-matched-line-includes-below-and-another-matched-line-includes-above#comment61666741_37059773) of [andlrc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc): "_OP is asking for how to get one line after for patternA and one line before for patternB. Not just the lines around patternA_"

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think Cyrus's code works perfectly for me. I accepted (?) this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poz --color=never '.*name.*\n.*|.*\n.*critical.*' file.txt
```

Output:

```
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_1" ;
  dtu_inst_d[19] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_muldivop_d[3] (out)                     0.00       1.12 r
critical voltage 1.00838
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_2" ;
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 r
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.11 f
critical voltage 1.00275
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_3" ;
  dtu_inst_d[22] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.10 f
critical voltage 1.00174
```

---

From `man grep`:

> `-P`: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
>
> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> `-z`: Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline

Comment: I see what you did there ;) Hackish use of `-z`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `grep` can handle your case, but AWK can:

```
awk '/name/{print;getline;print}/critical/{print prev;print}{prev=$0}' file.txt
```

Breakdown:

```
/name/ {      # Match name
  print;      # Print current line
  getline;    # Get next line 
  print;      # Print it
}
/critical/ {  # Match critical
  print prev; # Print previous line
  print;      # Print current line
}
{
  prev = $0   # Store previous line in prev
}
```

Comment: If you're ever tempted to use `getline`, make sure to read http://awk.info/?tip/getline first and then you usually won't and if you do you won't write it that way. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for how to find lines after a condition in awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for a well written article. I'm not a big user og awk. Tend to go for Perl when complexity goes up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/\$name/{c=2} c&&c--; /critical/{print p; print} {p=$0}' file

$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_1" ;
  dtu_inst_d[19] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_muldivop_d[3] (out)                     0.00       1.12 r
critical voltage 1.00838
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_2" ;
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 r
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.11 f
critical voltage 1.00275
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_3" ;
  dtu_inst_d[22] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.10 f
critical voltage 1.00174
```

Comment: Like the use of `c=2` and `c && c--`. Better than `print;getline;print` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'f || /critical/{print prev ORS $0; f=0} /name/{f=1} {prev=$0}' file
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_1" ;
  dtu_inst_d[19] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_muldivop_d[3] (out)                     0.00       1.12 r
critical voltage 1.00838
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_2" ;
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 r
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.11 f
critical voltage 1.00275
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_in_3" ;
  dtu_inst_d[22] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  ifu_exu_wen_d (out)                             0.00       1.10 f
critical voltage 1.00174
```