# Use grep to print only the context

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

Using [grep](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm), you can print lines that match your search query. Adding a `-C` option will print two lines of surrounding context, like this:

```
> grep -C 2 'lorem'
some context
some other context
**lorem ipsum**
another line
yet another line
```

Similarly, you can use `grep -B 2` or `grep -A 2` to print matching lines with two preceding or two following lines, respectively, for example:

```
> grep -A 2 'lorem'
**lorem ipsum**
another line
yet another line
```

Is it possible to skip the matching line and only print the context? Specifically, I would like to only print the line that is exactly 2 lines above a match, like this:

```
> <some magic command>
some context
```

Comment: Not in `grep` that I am aware of. Use `awk` like in this: [printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui this works for the following lines, but can i modify it to get the preceding lines? never used awk before.

Comment: Use `tac` to print the file backwards.

Comment: Can you then use `-v` to exclude the match line?

Comment: If you can allow two instances of `grep` to be used, you can try `grep -v "lorem" < <(grep -A2 "lorem" file)`

Answer (score 4):

If you can allow couple of `grep` instances to be used, you can try like as I mentioned in the comments section.

```
$ grep -v "lorem" < <(grep -A2 "lorem" file)
another line
yet another line

$ grep -A2 "lorem" file | grep -v "lorem"
another line
yet another line
```

If you are interested in a dose of `awk`, there is a cool way to do it as

```
$ awk -v count=2 '{a[++i]=$0;}/lorem/{for(j=NR-count;j<NR;j++)print a[j];}' file
another line
yet another line
```

It works by storing the entire file in its own array and after searching for the pattern `lorem`, the awk special variable which stores the row number(`NR`), points at the exact line in which the pattern is found. If we loop for 2 lines before it as dictated by the `awk` variable `-v count`, we can print the lines needed.

If you are interested in the printing the pattern also, just change the condition in for-loop as `j<=NR` instead of `j<NR`. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to do this purely through a `grep` command. If there’s only one instance of `lorem` in the text, you could pipe the output through `head`.

```
grep -B2 lorem t | head -1
```

If there may be multiple occurrence of `lorem`, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{second_previous=previous; previous=current_line; current_line=$0}; /lorem/ { print second_previous; }'
```

This awk command saves each line (along with the previous and the one before that) in variables so when it encounters a line containing `lorem`, it prints the second last line. If `lorem` happens to occur in the first or second line of the input, nothing would be printed.

Answer (score 1):

`awk`, as others have said, is your friend here. You don't need complex loops or arrays or other junk, though; basic patterns suffice.

When you use `-B N`, (and the `--no-group-separator` flag) you get output in groups of M=N+1 lines. To select precisely one of those lines (in your question, you want the very first of the group), you can use modular arithmetic (tested with GNU awk).

```
awk -vm=3 -vx=1 'NR%m==x{print}'
```

You can think of the lines being numbered like this: they count up until you reach the match, at which point they go back to zero. So set `m` to N+1 and `x` to the line you want to extract.

```
1 some context
2 some other context
0 **lorem ipsum**
```

So the final command would be

```
grep -B2 --no-group-separator lorem $input | awk -vm=3 -vx=1 'NR%m==x{print}'
```