# Why is grep so slow and memory intensive with -w (--word-regexp) flag?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I have a list of ids in a file and a data file (of ~3.2Gb in size), and I want to extract the lines in the data file that contain the id and also the next line. I did the following:

```
grep -A1 -Ff file.ids file.data | grep -v "^-" > output.data
```

This worked, but also extracted unwanted substrings, for example if the id is `EA4` it also pulled out the lines with `EA40`.

So I tried using the same command but adding the `-w` (`--word-regexp`) flag to the first `grep` to match whole words. However, I found my command now ran for >1 hour (rather than ~26 seconds) and also started using 10s of gigabytes of memory, so I had to kill the job.

Why did adding `-w` make the command so slow and memory grabbing? How can I efficiently run this command to get my desired output? Thank you

`file.ids` looks likes this:

```
>EA4
>EA9
```

`file.data` looks like this:

```
>EA4 text
data
>E40 blah
more_data
>EA9 text_again
data_here
```

`output.data` would look like this:

```
>EA4 text
data
>EA9 text_again
data_here
```

Comment: `awk` could be faster depending upon your input file, if you haven't tried it yet. If you can provide a sample of your both the files, logic in `awk` could be provided.

Comment: @Inian thanks, i've added some sample inputs and outputs

Comment: can you also add why `grep -v "^-"` is needed?

Comment: @Sundeep because grep -A1 outputs -- lines between matches

Comment: also, if you are using GNU grep, you can use `grep --no-group-separator -A1 -wFf file.ids file.data > output.data`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: You can provide a running time analysis for the `awk` solution in my answer, which I will be happy to remove if does not improve performance.

Comment: @Sundeep thanks but your `awk` solution returned a blank file to me

Comment: @Chris_Rands not sure why, I tested it for your input samples and it worked.. anyway, try the GNU grep one I posted if you have that option

Comment: @Sundeep I aplogise, the `file.ids` includes a `>` (see the edited input format), but it did't work either way for me unfortunately

Comment: oh, this one `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} a[$1]{c=2} c&&c--' file.ids file.data` works for me with modified input files....

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you, this does appear to be working as expected! If you can write it up as an answer (with a little explanation) I will gladly accept. Also, do you know what was happening when I added the `-w` flag to grep?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Can you share the performance difference between mine and Sundeep's solution for an analysis.

Comment: I don't know why `-w` would make it so much slower (but that flag is really needed to get correct output as per your question details), so good idea to wait for someone to address that issue... and as Inian suggested, you need to give perf comparison between the two answers, my answer was simply built on this classic Q&A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

Comment: what do you get for `grep --version` ? (and what OS?) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter grep (GNU grep) 2.25 on Arch Linux

Comment: and what is the result of `awk '{l=length;if (l>max)max=l}END{print NR "\t" max}' file` (for each file). Good luck.

Comment: incidentally, I don't think older Unix based `grep` (well `fgrep` actually) would have accepted a `-w` option. If you really want to know, you may have to post it to GNU as a bug or spend time plowing thru the source. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter thanks for your interest. that is line count and max line length? `294670 54` for `file.ids` and `19757294 29409` for `file.data`

Comment: the `-w` will scan the whole line looking for a match. (Complete mystery as to why it is hogging memory).  Its obvious that `break` in the deleted `awk` answer short circuits checking the whole line. Less obvious to me how @Sundeep 's version manages that ;-/ ? Sundeep, post that answer with a mini-explanation and I'll vote for it. Inian, undelete your msg and I'll vote for it because of its research value. Good luck to all.

Comment: how about if you change EA0 in your file.ids file for ^EA0\b (ditto every line),  this in particular allows it to exit each line as soon as it has passed the nth char.  Also allows you to drop the  | grep -v "^-".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grep -F string file` is simply looking for occurrences of `string` in  the file but `grep -w -F string file` has to check each character before and after `string` too to see if they are word characters or not. That's a **lot** of extra work and one possible implementation of it would be to first separate lines into every possible non-word-character-delimited string with overlaps of course so that could take up a lot of memory but idk if that's what's causing your memory usage or not.

In any case, grep is simply the wrong tool for this job since you only want to match against a specific field in the input file, you should be using awk instead:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} /^>/{f=($1 in ids)} f' file.ids file.data
>EA4 text
data
>EA9 text_again
data_here
```

The above assumes your "data" lines cannot start with `>`. If they can then tell us how to identify data lines vs id lines.

Note that the above will work no matter how many `data` lines you have between `id` lines, even if there's 0 or 100:

```
$ cat file.data
>EA4 text
>E40 blah
more_data
>EA9 text_again
data 1
data 2
data 3

$ awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} /^>/{f=($1 in ids)} f' file.ids file.data
>EA4 text
>EA9 text_again
data 1
data 2
data 3
```

Also, you don't need to pipe the output to `grep -v`:

```
grep -A1 -Ff file.ids file.data | grep -v "^-" > output.data
```

just do it all in the one script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} /^>/{f=($1 in ids)} f && !/^-/' file.ids file.data
```

Comment: Thanks, this is ~2 seconds faster than Sundeep's solution for my data set (with an identical output). And yes "data" lines cannot start with `>`

Comment: Also the solution working with multiple lines between id lines will be useful in some other cases I'm considering, so thanks for that too

Comment: Thanks, in fact the second `grep` is not needed now (this was just to process out the `--` lines created between matches by `grep -A1`. As Sundeep pointed out, I should have used the `--no-group-separator` flag instead.)

Comment: Sure, if you have the time to explain quickly, I'm curious, thanks

Comment: wrt the other solution posted that started with `NR==FNR { pats[$0]=1; next } { for(p in pats) if($1 ~ p) ...` - the reason it was so slow is that for every line of file.data it's looping through every value read from file.ids and stored in the array until it finds a match and doing a regexp comparison at every step to determine if there was a match or not. The other awk solutions are simply doing a hash lookup in the array of the first string from the relevant line.