# Print complete text block between two markers using awk, only if the block does not contain a specific keyword

Tags: regex, awk, regex-negation

I have a certain pattern in my file as so:

```
....
BEGIN
any text1
any text2
END
....
BEGIN
any text3
garbage text
any text4
END
....
BEGIN
any text5
any text6
END
...
```

`BEGIN` and `END` are my markers, and I want to extract all the text between the markers only if the block does not contain `'garbage text`'. So my expectation is to extract the blow blocks:

```
any text1
any text2

any text5
any text6
```

How do I do it in awk? I know I can do something like:

```
awk '/BEGIN/{f=1;next}/END/{f=0;}f' file.log
```

to extract the lines between the two markers, but how do I further refine the results by further filtering based on absence of '`garbage text`'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/END/{if (rec !~ /garbage text/) print rec} {rec=rec $0 ORS} /BEGIN/{rec=""}' file
any text1
any text2

any text5
any text6
```

The above assumes every END is paired with a preceding BEGIN. WIth GNU awk for multi-char RS you could alternatively do:

```
$ awk -v RS='END\n' '{sub(/.*BEGIN\n/,"")} RT!="" && !/garbage text/' file
any text1
any text2

any text5
any text6
```

btw instead of:

```
awk '/BEGIN/{f=1;next}/END/{f=0;}f' file.log
```

your original code should be just:

```
awk '/END/{f=0} f; /BEGIN/{f=1}' file.log
```

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for related idioms.