# How can I use awk to detect lines that have only one field and print it together with the next line?

Tags: bash, awk

I've a file.txt written in this way:

```
0 
0.421915 0.420615 192000
0.420397 0.420802 192000
1
0.423915 0.423681 768000
0.421658 0.421474 768000
```

and I'd like to take the line with only one column and the following one.
Is it ok to use awk and how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: at least, show how should look the expected result

Comment: Do you mean something like:  **1** and a line after **1**?

Comment: try `awk 'NF==1{c=2}c-->0'`

Comment: @PS consider what would happen to that if the file was huge and `c` wrapped around negative maxint. Protect the decrement with `c&&c--` so the decrement only happens when c is greater than zero.

Answer (score 4):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NF==1 && (getline nl)>0{print $0 ORS nl}' file
```

The output:

```
0
0.421915 0.420615 192000
1
0.423915 0.423681 768000
```

---

- `NF==1` - considering only lines with one column
- `getline nl` - getting the next line and assigning it to variable `nl` (next line)
- `(getline nl)>0` - the ***getline*** command returns **1** if it finds a record and **0** if it encounters the end of the file
- `print $0 ORS nl` - print *the line with only one column and the following one* (as required)

Comment: To explain the solution - NF==1 checks to see if there is one field in the record/line with a default field delimiter of space. When this condition is met, the next line is read into the variable nl and then the current line is printed ($0) along with the default record separator - RS (carriage return) and then the variable nl.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, so you should have been told that before downvoting

Comment: Sorry Roman, it wasn't me downgrading, I pressed the poxy carriage return/post by accident. I've just edited

Comment: @RamanSailopal, I've recovered it. That was tricky, don't do that )

Comment: ok, that works. and if I want not the first following row but the second one?

Comment: @ila, if you show the desired result, I'll try to help

Comment: I'd like something as:                                                                            ****0.420397 0.420802 192000                                                           ****0.421658 0.421474 768000                                                                 (*** means a new linea, sorry I'm new)     The second lines after the one with just NF=1. Thank you

Comment: @ila, should it be printed along with main line (which has one column)? Just this 2 lines: `0.420397 0.420802 192000
0.421658 0.421474 768000
` ?

Comment: Make sure to read and fully understand everything discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're considering opening the `getline` can of worms. In this case, for example, if your input file ended in a single field then the `getline` would quietly fail so `nl` would remain it's previous value and you'd end up copying the second-last line into the output after the last line, thereby producing output that looks perfectly correct but in fact is completely wrong and you got no indication a problem had occurred. There are other issues too - just read the article then don't do it.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks, your supposition about *input file ended in a single field* was reasonable (I didn't think of that). Fixed

Comment: Youre welcome. It now wont print the last line at all if it's a single field though. There's just too much to consider when you use getline (unless you **really** need it) - all these rainy day cases just come crawling out of the woodwork and bite you later. And you can't easily enhance it - try adding a simple `print |"cat>&2"` to output every line to stderr for debugging for example. btw it won;t change the output in this case but in general you should be using `ORS` instead of `RS` in output statements (since that's what it is for).

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with grep :

`grep -E -A 1 "^[0-9]+$" yourfile.txt`

Comment: you no need to use `*` because it matches the empty line as well

Comment: You're right, i'll change it to a `+`, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Although this should work, the input text posted by the OP has a space at the end of the first line which would cause this reg exp to fail to detect. Instead, using `"^[0-9]+[ ]*$"` should work, but remember also that `grep` will introduce a `--` separator line between successive matches so you'd need to add something like `| grep -v "\-\-"` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with:

```
awk 'NF==1{p=1;print$0;}NF!=1{if(p==1){print$0;p=0}}' file.txt
```

**Output**:

```
0 
0.421915 0.420615 192000
1
0.423915 0.423681 768000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NF==1{c=2} c&&c--' file
0
0.421915 0.420615 192000
1
0.423915 0.423681 768000
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for an explanation of that and more awk range idioms.