# Print between specific ranges - sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can we achieve this using sed or awk?

**I have now included the text in a code block to make it clear**.

**The code block part should be printed  -  is the requirement.**

LOGIC 1:

**The text 'abc' will be our keyword here which will be unique and will only occur within the code block part**

**So we'll have to search for 'abc' and from that line till the last occurrence of 'abc' all lines should be printed inclusive**

LOGIC 2:

**Based on page numbers i.e. select text between page 1 and page n again inclusive**
Note: 'Page 1' and 'Page 1 - Page n' can come multiple times.

The whole text is a part of a 4GB file which needs to be parsed for similar occurrences.

Apologies for not being clear.

## START OF TEXT IN THE FILE:

Xyz       Page: 1

a

b

c

d

e

QWE       Page: 1

e

r

t

y

```
asdabc       Page: 1

t

y

u

I

o

ghjabc       Page: 2

e

d

c

b

bnmabc       Page: 3

uia

asd

ads
```

thm       Page: 1

as

das

da

## END OF TEXT IN FILE

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 and if afterwards you still have a question then read [ask] and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve it by using `awk`,

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0} /.*Page/{if(index($0,"abc")!=0){a=1} else{a=0}} a==1{print}' <Your_File>
```

Output:

```
asdabc       Page: 1

t

y

u

I

o

ghjabc       Page: 2

e

d

c

b

bnmabc       Page: 3

uia

asd

ads
```

Here's what I do here,

1. set the flag 'a' to determine if print or not
2. find string "Page" in the line, and then check if "abc" in it
3. start to print lines
4. print the line until next "Page" show up but no "abc" in it

Comment: Thanks CWLiu. Sorry for the confusion - can you check the required now and let me know if it is possible using sed or awk?

Comment: If you don't give us the logic or specific patterns for code block part, it's hard to extract it.

Comment: Bang! Many Thanks Liu... :)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know what exactly you want to print, but you should be able to use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/start pattern/,/end pattern/p' <file>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack but I was unable to put my requirements exactly the first time I guess. Can you have a look now please?