# How to use cut lines based on a pattern match?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with the output as below

```
--B32934--
descr:     X
descr:     Y
descr:     Z
--B20484
descr:     A
descr:     B
descr:     C
--B41946
descr:     1
descr:     2
descr:     3
descr:     4
```

I just need the --BXXXX number and the first line, the rest of the lines need to be stripped out from the file. Is it possible to delete the lines >1 based on the pattern match --B?

For example under "--B32934" i just want "descr:X". The rest of the lines need to be deleted.

Desired result should look like this

```
--B32934--
descr:     X
```

Comment: post the desired result

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply. The desired result should look like this


--B32934--
descr: X


--B20484

descr: A



--B41946

descr: 1

Comment: Edit additional information into the question. Too hard to read in the comments. And note that there are fancy buttons for formatting at the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

-- ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/^--B[0-9]+/{ r=NR; print }(NR-1)==r' file
```

- `/^--B[0-9]+/` - if the line starts with *pattern*
- `r=NR` - hold the record number
- `(NR-1)==r` - if it's the next line after the pattern line

To capture the following 2 lines after the pattern line - use this approach:

```
awk '/^--B[0-9]+/{ r=NR; print }(NR-1)==r || (NR-2)==r' file
```

---

-- GNU ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n '/--B[0-9]*/{N;p;}' file
```

- `N` - add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space (GNU extension)

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
--B32934--
descr: X
--B20484
descr: A
--B41946
descr: 1
```

Comment: my apologies, i am a bit to sed, when i try this on my mac, i get the error below

sed -n '/--AS[0-9]*/{h;N;p}' test


sed: 1: "/--AS[0-9]*/{h;N;p}": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: @venkyjack, it was GNU sed. If so, use my awk approach

Comment: The awk commands work on my mac, but just for my info could you please let me know what the $0 and B[0-9] does? Thanks. I was asking because incase i need 2 lines i need to know what needs to be modified.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just add `;` to end to work with both sed versions... if you are using `[0-9]*` you might as well remove it... and `h` is not needed as well... `sed -n '/--B/{N;p;}'`... and can also use `grep -A1 --no-group-separator '\--B'` but required `GNU grep`

Comment: @venkyjack, see my details

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for the sed command, that works on my mac, if i need two lines displayed how should i modify the command?

Comment: In `awk`: `$0~/something/` can be just `/something/`

Comment: @venkyjack add as many `N;` as you need... `GNU grep` is easiest choice as you can directly give number to `-A` option

Comment: (You may want to change the explanation below as well)

Comment: One more thing: `(NR-1)==r{ print }` can be just `NR-1==r`

Comment: @hek2mgl, yeah, going to maximal shortening

Comment: @sundeep Thank you. In the SED an extra letter of N prints the two lines for me

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you for the explanation, its been very helpful. If i need to print 2 lines instead of 1 what variable do i change? I tried with an additional N but that stripped out all the lines :(

Comment: @venkyjack, this one: `sed -n '/--B[0-9]*/{N;N;p;}' file`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you, with the sed i figured out its an extra N, just wondering what to modify with the awk you sent me earlier

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Brilliant that worked. You guys are champions

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest in your awk command is there any way i can add a new blank line after each output?

Comment: @venkyjack, in what case?

Comment: After the descr: for each B[0-9] just wanted to check if a new blank line can be added in the command awk '/^--B[0-9]+/{ r=NR; print }(NR-1)==r || (NR-2)==r'

Comment: @venkyjack, unclear, exactly in what place newline should be added?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest After each descr the blank line needs to be placed

Comment: @venkyjack, use this one: `awk '/^--B[0-9]+/{ r=NR; print }(NR-1)==r{ print $0 ORS }' file`

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'p{print;p=0}/^-/{print;p=1}' file
```

Explanation:

If the variable `p` is true, print the current line, set p back to `0` (false). If the line starts with a `-`, print the current line and set `p` to `1` (true) (in order to print the next line).

Comment: Thank you. This works too, but if i need 2 lines instead of 1 what variable do i modify?

Comment: @venkyjack see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105 for all sorts of things you can do... `awk '/^-/{p=3} p && p--'` would be one way for matching line and 2 afterwards

Comment: @Sundeep thank you, is there any way i can add a blank new line after each output?

Comment: Set the output record separator to two newlines: `awk 'p{print;p=0}/^-/{print;p=1}' ORS='\n\n' file`

Comment: @hek2mgl thank you but this adds extra blank line between the B and the descr: , i just need between each set of B and descr: for eg: --B32934--
descr:     X
descr:     Y
descr:     Z


--B20484
descr:     A
descr:     B
descr:     C

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^--B\S\+/!d;n' file
```

Delete any line that does not begin with `--B` followed by one or more non-space characters. Otherwise print that line and the following.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with `grep`

`grep -e '^--B[0-9]\+' --no-group-separator -A 1 file`

outputs:

```
--B32934--
descr:     X
--B20484
descr:     A
--B41946
descr:     1
```

Comment: thank you, is there any way i can add a new blank line after each output?

Comment: @venkyjack Yep, simply use `grep -e '^--B[0-9]\+' -A 1 --group-separator "" file`