# awk to skip lines up to and including pattern

Tags: awk, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to use `awk` to skip all lines including a specific pattern `/^#CHROM/` and start processing on the line below. The `awk` does execute but currently returns all lines in the `tab-delimited` `file`.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
##INFO=<ID=ANN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="My custom annotation">
##source_20170530.1=vcf-annotate(r953) -d key=INFO,ID=ANN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description=My custom annotation -c CHROM,FROM,TO,INFO/ANN
##INFO=<ID=,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Variant quality">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT
chr1    948846  .   T   TA  NA  NA
chr2    948852  .   T   TA  NA  NA
chr3    948888  .   T   TA  NA  NA
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR>/^#CHROM/ {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"ID=1"$6,"ID=2"$7}' file
```

**desiered output**

```
chr1    948846  .   T   TA  ID1=NA  ID2=NA
chr2    948852  .   T   TA  ID1=NA  ID2=NA
chr3    948888  .   T   TA  ID1=NA  ID2=NA
```

Comment: try `/^#CHROM/{f=1;next} f{print ...}` or `f{print ...} /^#CHROM/{f=1}`

Comment: `/^#CHROM/` is a regexp that's equivalent to `$0~/^#CHROM/`. Do you think the result of that comparison is a line number or a boolean true/false? If a boolean, why are you comparing it to the current line number (NR)? If a line number, what do you think the result of testing to see if the current line number is greater than the current line number would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} f{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"ID1="$6,"ID2="$7} /^#CHROM/{f=1}' file
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for details on this and other awk search idioms. Yours is a variant of "b" on that page.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '/^#CHROM/{ r=NR }r && NR>r{ $6="ID=1"$6; $7="ID=2"$7; print }' file
```

The output:

```
chr1    948846  .   T   TA  ID=1NA  ID=2NA
chr2    948852  .   T   TA  ID=1NA  ID=2NA
chr3    948888  .   T   TA  ID=1NA  ID=2NA
```

---

- `/^#CHROM/{ r=NR }` - capturing the *pattern* line number

---

The alternative approach would look as below:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '/^#CHROM/{ f=1; next }f{ $6="ID=1"$6; $7="ID=2"$7; print }' file
```

Comment: Just swap the blocks round, so `f` is evaluated the line after it is set.

Comment: Thank you all :).