# How to print three consecutive lines after a pattern, which is in different file

Tags: awk, sed

I am beginner, hoping somebody can help me out.  I would like to use awk (or sed) to do this task.

I have two files,

File 1

```
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:17896:1432
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:14465:1433
```

File 2

```
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:17896:1432 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCAATGTGATCTGTTTACATTCCAACTCAGCTTCCTCTTGTAAATGTTTTTCTTTTTAC
+
8ABC-6F,C<,CFF9FGGAE9FGFF9<EFF9,CEEEEGGGG9E,,,C<FFFGGGGGGGGGG
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:14465:1433 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCATGATGGTACGAAAGTACACATTTTATTTCTTATAAGCAATGGGTTTACTCAGCCTGA
+
@CC<CA9F<<FCFE>87@FCFAF?FFGG9FFFFGGCF9,<EA8FC8EFFGEFGG98@FFC8
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:15447:1444 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CTCTATCTAGAGTTGCCTTCATCAGTTTATCAAAAACACAACCTTAAAAAGGCAACCCCTG
+
AACC@FFGA<@9FF9EEFGF9FF9<FFFEFF99,,<B8C<8@FFGD,,,,,:C8<FEFEF8
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:15876:1444 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CTCTTTATTTAGTTTTAACTTATCTCAAAAATTACTCGACCTAAAAAATTTGGCCTGTTTA
+
-8CCCG-EFFA9FFFG98FFF9FEEE9,,,,CFAEFF7,@CF,,,,,+CEF9,CFF8EFF,
```

The out put what I want is as follows. So if the line in file 1 match with line in the file 2, print the line in file 2 together with three consecutive lines. Lines in file 1 are all unique IDs.

```
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:17896:1432 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCAATGTGATCTGTTTACATTCCAACTCAGCTTCCTCTTGTAAATGTTTTTCTTTTTAC
+
8ABC-6F,C<,CFF9FGGAE9FGFF9<EFF9,CEEEEGGGG9E,,,C<FFFGGGGGGGGGG
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:14465:1433 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCATGATGGTACGAAAGTACACATTTTATTTCTTATAAGCAATGGGTTTACTCAGCCTGA
+
@CC<CA9F<<FCFE>87@FCFAF?FFGG9FFFFGGCF9,<EA8FC8EFFGEFGG98@FFC8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a{c=4} c&&c--' file1 file2
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:17896:1432 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCCAATGTGATCTGTTTACATTCCAACTCAGCTTCCTCTTGTAAATGTTTTTCTTTTTAC
+
8ABC-6F,C<,CFF9FGGAE9FGFF9<EFF9,CEEEEGGGG9E,,,C<FFFGGGGGGGGGG
@HWI-M01162:73:000000000-A7TPE:1:1101:14465:1433 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CCCATGATGGTACGAAAGTACACATTTTATTTCTTATAAGCAATGGGTTTACTCAGCCTGA
+
@CC<CA9F<<FCFE>87@FCFAF?FFGG9FFFFGGCF9,<EA8FC8EFFGEFGG98@FFC8
```

Comment: Very brilliant use of `c&&c--`

Comment: Thanks you can see more of it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 :-).

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

This **awk** will do that:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{k[FNR]=$0; next} 
     {data[FNR]=$0; next}
     END{
       for (i=1;i in k;i++) {
           for (j=1; j in data; j++){
                if (data[j]~k[i]){
                   for (x=0; x<4; x++)
                       print data[j+x]
                   j+=x
                }
           }
        }
      }' f1 f2
```

Comment: Hi Dawg, Thank you very much!! It works for my files!!