# How to select text in a file until a certain string using grep, sed or awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a huge file (this is just a sample) and I would like to select all lines with `"Ph_gUFAC1083"` and all after until reach one that doesn't have the code (in this example `Ph_gUFAC1139`)

```
>uce_353_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_353
TTTAGCCATAGAAATGCAGAAATAATTAGAAGTGCCATTGTGTACAGTGCCTTCTGGACT
GGGCTGAAGGTGAAGGAGAAAGTATCATACTATCCTTGTCAGCTGCAAGGGTAATTACTG
CTGGCTGAAATTACTCAACATTTGTTTATAAGCTCCCCAGAGCATGCTGTAAATAGATTG
TCTGTTATAGTCCAATCACATTAAAACGCTGCTCCTTGCAAACTGCTACCTCCTGTTTTC
TGTAAGCTAGACAGAGAAAGCCTGCTGCTCACTTACTGAGCACCAAGCACTGAAGAGCTA
TGTTTAATGTGATTGTTTTCATTAGCTCTTCTCTGTCTGATATTACATTTATAATTTGCT
GGGCTTGAAGACTGGCATGTTGCATTGCTTTCATTTACTGTAGTAAGAGTGAATAGCTCT
AT
>uce_101_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_101
TTGGGCTTTATTTCCACCTTAAAATCTTTACCTGGCCGTGATCTGTTGTTCCATTACTGG
AGGGCAAAAATGGGAGGAATTGTCTGGGCTAAATTGCAATTAGGCAGCCCTGAGAGAGGC
TGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGT
AGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGAAGAG
GAGAGTTAATTGCATGTTACAGTGAGTGTAATGCCTAGATAACCTTGCATTTAATGCTAT
TCTTAGCCCTGCTGCCAAGACTTCTACAGAGCCTCTCTCTGCAGGAAGTCATTAAAGCTG
TGAGTAGATAATGCAGGCTCAGTGAAACCTAAGTGGCAACAATATA
>uce_171_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_171
CATGGAAAACGAGGAAAAGCCATATCTTCCAGGCCATTAATATTACTACGGAGACGTCTT
CATATCGCCGTAATTACAGCAGATCTCAAAGTGGCACAACCAAGACCAGCACCAAAGCTA
AAATAACTCGCAGGAGCAGGCGAGCTGCTTTTGCAGCCCTCAGTCCCAGAAATGCTCGGT
AGCTTTTCTTAAAATAGACAGCCTGTAAATAAGGTCTGTGAACTCAATTGAAGGTGGCTG
TTTCTGAATTAGTCAGCCCTCACAAGGCTCTCGGCCTACATGCTAGTACATAAATTGTCC
ACTTTACCACCAGACAAGAAAGATTAGAGTAATAAACACGGGGCATTAGCTCAGCTAGAG
AAACACACCAGCCGTTACGCACACGCGGGATTGCCAAGAACTGTTAACCCCACTCTCCAG
AAACGCACACAAAAAAACAAGTTAAAGCCATGACATCATGGGAA

>uce_4300_Ph_gUFAC1139 |uce_4300
ATTAAAAATACAATCCTCATGTTTGCATTTTGCAGTCGTCAACAAGAAATTGAAGAGAAA
CTCATAGAGGAAGAAACTGCTCGAAGGGTGGAAGAACTTGTAGCTAAACGCGTGGAAGAA
GAGCTGGAGAAAAGAAAGGATGAGATTGAGCGAGAGGTTCTCCGCAGGGTGGAGGAGGCT
AAGCGCATCATGGAAAAACAGTTGCTCGAAGAACTCGAGCGACAGCGACAAGCTGAACTT
GCAGCACAAAAAGCCAGAGAGGTAACGCTCGGTCGTTTGGAAAGTAGAGACAGTCCATGG
CAAAACTTTCAGTGTCGGTTTGTGCCTCCTGTTCGGTTCAGAAAGAGATGGAATACAGCA
AATCTAATTCCCTTCTCATATAAACTTGCATTGCTGCGAAACTTAATTTCTAGCCTATTC
AGAGGAGCTCACTGATATTTAAACAGTTACTCTCCTAAAACCTGAACAAGGATACTTGAT
TCTTAATGGAACTGACCTACATATTTCAGAATTGTTTGAAACTTTTGCCATGGCTGCAGG
ATTATTCAGCAGTCCTTTCATTTT
>uce_1039_Ph_gUFAC1139 |uce_1039
ATTAGTGGAATACAAATATGCAAAAACCAAACAGTTTGGTGCTATAATGTGAAAAGAAAT
TTACACCAATCTTATTTTTAATTTGTATGGGAACATTTTTACCACAAATTCCATATTTTA
ATAATACTATCCCAACTCTATTTTTTAGACTCATTTTGTCACTGTTTTGTAACAGAAACA
CTGTAAATATTATAGATGTGGTAAACTATTATACTTGTTTTCTTATAAATGAAATGATCT
GTGCCAACACTGACAAAATGAATTAATGTGTTACTAAGGCAACAGTCACATTATATGCTT
TCTCTTTCACAGTATGCGGTAGAGCATATGGTTTACTCTTAATGGAACACTAGCTTCTCA
TTAACATACCAGTAGCAATGTCAGAACTTACAAACCAGCATAACAGAGAAATGGAAAAAC
TTATAAATTAGACCCTTTCAGTATTATTGAGTAGAAAATGACTGATGTTCCAAGGTACAA
TATTTAGCTAATACAGTGCCCTTTTCTGCATCTTTCTTCTCAAAGGAAAAAAAAATCCTC
AAAAAAAACCAGAGCAAGAAACCTAACTTTTTCTTGT
```

I already tried several alternatives without success, the closest I reached was

```
sed -n '/Ph_gUFAC1083/, />/p' file.txt
```

that gave me that:

```
>uce_2347_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_2347
GCTTTTCTATGCAGATTTTTTCTAATTCTCTCCCTCCCCTTGCTTCTGTCAGTGTGAAGC
CCACACTAAGCATTAACAGTATTAAAAAGAGTGTTATCTATTAGTTCAATTAGACATCAG
ACATTTACTTTCCAATGTATTTGAAGACTGATTTGATTTGGGTCCAATCATTTAAAAATA
AGAGAGCAGAACTGTGTACAGAGCTGTGTACAGATATCTGTAGCTCTGAAGTCTTAATTG
CAAATTCAGATAAGGATTAGAAGGGGCTGTATCTCTGTAGACCAAAGGTATTTGCTAATA
CCTGAGATATAAAAGTGGTTAAATTCAATATTTACTAATTTAGGATTTCCACTTTGGATT
TTGATTAAGCTTTTTGGTTGAAAACCCCACATTATTAAGCTGTGATGAGGGAAAAAGCAA
CTCTTTCATAAGCCTCACTTTAACGCTTTATTTCAAATAATTTATTTTGGACCTTCTAAA
G
>uce_353_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_353

>uce_101_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_101
TTGGGCTTTATTTCCACCTTAAAATCTTTACCTGGCCGTGATCTGTTGTTCCATTACTGG
AGGGCAAAAATGGGAGGAATTGTCTGGGCTAAATTGCAATTAGGCAGCCCTGAGAGAGGC
TGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGT
AGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGAAGAG
GAGAGTTAATTGCATGTTACAGTGAGTGTAATGCCTAGATAACCTTGCATTTAATGCTAT
TCTTAGCCCTGCTGCCAAGACTTCTACAGAGCCTCTCTCTGCAGGAAGTCATTAAAGCTG
TGAGTAGATAATGCAGGCTCAGTGAAACCTAAGTGGCAACAATATA
>uce_171_Ph_gUFAC1083 |uce_171
```

Do you know how to do it using grep, sed or awk?

Thx

Comment: @hek2mgl ? can you help me?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^>/{if(match($0,"Ph_gUFAC1083")){s=1} else s=0}s' file
```

I made a simple criteria for your request,

- If the the start of the line is `>`, we're going to judge if `"Ph_gUFAC1083"` existed, if yes, set s=1, set s=0 otherwise.
- For the line that doesn't start with `>`, the value of `s` would be retained.
- The final `s` in the `awk` command decide if the line to be printed (s=1) or not (s=0).

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is every line with `Ph_gUFAC1139` plus block of lines after that line until the next line starting with `>`, then the following awk snippet might do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=ORS=">"} /Ph_gUFAC1139/' file.txt
```

This uses the `>` character as a *record separator*, then simply displays records that contain the text you're interested in.

If you wanted to be able to provide the search string using a variable, you'd do it something like this:

```
$ val="Ph_gUFAC1139"
$ awk -v s="$val" 'BEGIN {RS=ORS=">"} $0 ~ s' file.txt
```

---

**UPDATE**

A comment mentions that the solution above shows trailing record separators rather than leading ones.  You can adapt your output to match your input by reversing this order manually:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=ORS=">" } /Ph_gUFAC1139/ { printf "%s%s",ORS,$0 }' file.txt
```

Note that in the initial examples, a "match" of the regex would invoke awk's default "action", which is to print the line. The default action is invoked if no action is specified within the script. The code (immediately) above includes an action .. which prints the record, preceded by the separator.

Comment: Thank you @ghoti, almost there, I want to keep the ">" at the beginning of each one!

Comment: That's what `BEGIN {RS=ORS=">"}` achieves, by setting ORS in addition to RS. I've switched the first example so that it no longer uses the `-v RS=">"` notation, so that you now have consistent examples.

Comment: Can you tell me the full command please? I-m trying `awk -v BEGIN {RS=ORS='>'} '/Ph_gUFAC1139/'` but is not working!

Comment: Mind your quotes! Quotes are VERY important in shell. Use the ones in my examples. The awk script should be enclosed entirely in single quotes, and may contain double quotes (but not single ones) within it. The `-v` option gets used to *set a variable*.  `man awk` for usage instructions and further examples.

Comment: I just figured out two small details, the first match doesn't have the  `>` and the very last line has one lonely `>`! do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Ah, fun...  awk shows you the record separator *after* the record. To change that behaviour, you need to handle this output manually.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/h;G;/Ph_gUFAC1083/P;d' file
```

Store each line beginning with `>` in the hold space (HS) and then append the HS to every line. If any line contains the string `Ph_gUFAC1083` print the first line in the pattern space (PS) and discard the everything else.

N.B. the regexp for the match may be amended to `/\n.*Ph_gUFAC1083/` if the string match may occur in any line.

Comment: Nice. Curious: what part of this do you suspect is GNU-specific? It seems to work fine for me in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

This program is used to find the block which starts with     Ph_gUFAC1083 and ends with any statement other than Ph_gUFAC1139

```
cat inp.txt |
    awk ' 
    BEGIN{begin=0}
    {
        # Ignore blank lines
        if( $0 ~ /^$/ )
        {
           print $0
           next
        } 

        # mark the line that contains Ph_gUFAC1083 and print it
        if( $0 ~ /Ph_gUFAC1083/ )
        { 
            begin=1
            print $0
        }    
        else  
        {    
            # if the line contains Ph_gUFAC1083 and Ph_gUFAC1139 was found before it, print it
            if( begin == 1 && ( $0 ~ /Ph_gUFAC1139/ ) ) 
            {
                print $0
            }
            else 
            {
                # found a line which doesnt contain Ph_gUFAC1139 , mark the end of the block.
                begin = 0
            } 
        }
    }'
```