# Grep all lines after first match of particular word. Output should exclude the matching line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

```
 $cat data
 123
 ABC
 DEF
 GHI
 ABC
 EFG
```

Output should be

```
DEF
GHI
ABC
EFG
```

Matching word will be **"ABC"**. So it will detect for the first occurrence of the word "ABC" and will print from next n lines after matching line

Comment: See b or e at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001. Your requirements aren't clear so idk which one you need but it is one of those two best I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/ABC/ && !f{ f=1;next }f' file
```

- `/ABC/ && !f` - on encountering line with `ABC` and with unset mark/flag `!f` - set the flag `f=1` as indicator of the 1st occurrence of `ABC` line; `next` - skip the current pattern line
- `f` - print the line while the mark/flag is set

The output:

```
DEF
GHI
ABC
EFG
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed '1,/ABC/d' data
DEF
GHI
ABC
EFG
```

This applies the delete function of `sed` (`d`) to all lines in the range 1 to `/ABC/` (the first line that matches the pattern `ABC`). This deletes the first few lines, up to and including the line containing `ABC`.

The default action of printing all lines will be applied to the remaining lines.

---

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/ABC/ && !f && f = 1 { next } f' data
DEF
GHI
ABC
EFG
```

If `ABC` is found on a line and `f` is not set, set `f` to 1 and skip to the next line. If `f` is set, print the line, otherwise discard input.

Comment: Your first example is not quite right, it only deletes `ABC` not all the preceding lines. I think you want `sed '1,/ABC/d' data`

Comment: @MarkSetchell You are absolutely correct. Sloppy typing. Fixing it now. It's what I wrote in the text...

Comment: @MarkSetchell :-) In this case I had a wrong solution in the browser and a correct solution in my shell and decided, against my better judgement, to edit by hand rather than copy and paste...