# Using -v option to invert multi-line grep results with grep -A not working

Tags: linux, grep, text-processing

I have a list like the following:

```
Name_JR_1
1.1.1.1
Name_SR_1
2.2.2.2
Name_NONE_1
3.3.3.3
```

If I want to chose all associated name with following numerical syntax I can look for a pattern and print the matching line plus the after context or next line using the `-A1` option, as follows:

`grep "JR" -A1 file_name`

and this will print what I want:

```
Name_JR_1
1.1.1.1
```

I need a way to invert this however, where I can REMOVE all entries which match the search pattern. However using the `-v` option with this syntax doesen't give me the results I want:

```
grep -v "JR" -A1 file_name
```

What I want the output to be like after this command is as follows:

```
Names_SR_1
2.2.2.2
Name_NONE_1
3.3.3.3.
```

Comment: Why the negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '/JR/{getline;next} 1' file
Name_SR_1
2.2.2.2
Name_NONE_1
3.3.3.3
```

#### How it works

1. `/JR/{getline;next}`

   This selects the lines containing `JR`.  For those lines, this instructs awk to get the next line (`getline`) and then to skip the rest of the commands and start over on the following line (`next`).
2. `1`

   For any lines that don't have `JR` in them, this prints the line.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '/JR/||f==1{f=!f;next}1' file
Name_SR_1
2.2.2.2
Name_NONE_1
3.3.3.3
```

If we see `JR` or flag is up, reverse the flag and skip to next line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sed`

```
$ sed '/JR/{N;d;}' ip.txt
Name_SR_1
2.2.2.2
Name_NONE_1
3.3.3.3
```

- `N` will add next line to pattern space and then `d` will delete it

  - use `N;N` for two more lines, `N;N;N` for three more lines and so on

For a generic solution with `awk`

```
$ awk '/JR/{c=2} !(c && c--)' ip.txt
Name_SR_1
2.2.2.2
Name_NONE_1
3.3.3.3
```

- here `2` is count of matching line and one line after
- so for `-A2` equivalent, you'd need `c=3`
- See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern) for plenty of cases related to this