# Replace Nth linewise search result

Tags: sed, text-processing

I want to replace all excluding first result

I have txt file:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I want to get this:

```
AAA
BBB <-- stay same
CCC
AAA
XXX <-- 2nd find replaced
CCC
AAA
XXX <-- 3rd and nth find replaced
CCC
```

I looking something similar to this, but for whole lines, not for words in lines

```
sed -i 's/AAA/XXX/2' ./test01
```

Comment: I've edited out the answer from question... to indicate solved status, please accept the answer that helped you by clicking the tick button..

Comment: Obciously you want to replace `BBB` wtih `XXX` and not `AAA`

Answer (score 4):

Use branching:

```
sed -e'/BBB/ {ba};b; :a {n;s/BBB/XXX/;ba}'
```

I.e. on the first BBB, we branch to `:a`, otherwise `b` without parameter starts processing of the next line.

Under `:a`, we read in a new line, replace all `BBB` by `XXX` and branch to `a` again.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk '{++a[$0];$0=$0=="AAA"&&(a[$0]==2||a[$0]==3)?$0 ORS "XXX":$0} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: This isn't working it's second and third BBB line which should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ # replace all occurrences greater than s
$ # use gsub instead of sub to replace all occurrences in line
$ # whole line: awk -v s=1 '$0=="AAA" && ++c>s{$0="XXX"} 1' ip.txt
$ awk -v s=1 '/AAA/ && ++c>s{sub(/AAA/, "XXX")} 1' ip.txt 
AAA
BBB
CCC
XXX
BBB
CCC
XXX
BBB
CCC

$ # replace exactly when occurrence == s
$ awk -v s=2 '/AAA/ && ++c==s{sub(/AAA/, "XXX")} 1' ip.txt 
AAA
BBB
CCC
XXX
BBB
CCC
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Further reading: [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '/BBB/{c++;if(c >=2)sub(/BBB/,"XXX")}1' file

AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
XXX
CCC
AAA
XXX
CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your file does not contain `null` chars (`\0`) you can fool sed to consider the whole file as a big string by intstructing sed to separate records using null char `\0` instead of the default `\n` with sed option `-z`:

```
$ sed -z 's/BBB/XXX/2g' file66
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
XXX
CCC
AAA
XXX
CCC
```

`/2g` at the end means from second match and then globally.

You can combine `-i` with `-z` without problem.