# Changing txt file via Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a  text file that looks like

```
file:/path/to/file
..
..
DA:34,0,0
DA:86,0,0
DA:87,0,0
..
DA:89,0,0
file:/path/to/file
..
DA:23,0,1
..
DA:24,0,1
DA:25,0,1
..
```

I just want to keep the first line beginning with "DA" after the line beginning with "file". Other lines starting with "DA" have to be deleted. There are a lot of other lines (I marked them with ".."), they also need to be kept.

The result should look like this:

```
file:/path/to/file
..
..
DA:34,0,0
..
file:/path/to/file
..
DA:23,0,1
..
..
```

Can anybody help me? I would be really grateful. Thanks

Comment: What have you searched for, what did you find, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @tripleee  not really a duplicate! The difference is that some lines need to be printed.

Comment: It would seem rather pointless to reopen just to have this reclosed for lack of attempt. Probably the OP should simply post a new and improved question with their best attempt if they still need further help.

Comment: I used this command but I can't do that to check for the next "DA" line after line starting with "file" awk '!c && /^DA/{c=1;print;next} !/^DA/ {print} END{print l}' $i.info > temp.info && mv temp.info $i.info

Comment: @MatusSpita, if you want to add code that demonstrates that your question isn't a duplicate, you should probably [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52833141/edit) and add the code to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very closely related to [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105).

What you are after is:

```
awk '/^file/{f=1}(f&&/^DA/){f=0;print}!/^DA/' file
```

**How does this work?**

- **`/^file/{f=1}`:** If you find a line which starts with the word "file", set a flag `f` to `1`
- **`(f&&/^DA/){f=0;print}`:** If the flag `f` is not zero, and the line starts with `DA`, print the line and set the flag to zero. This makes sure you only print the first `DA` after `file`.
- **`!/^DA/`:** print all the lines that do not start with `DA`

A shorter version:

```
awk '/^file/{f=1}(f--&&/^DA/);!/^DA/' file
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, very helpfull. Sorry, I am new here, I will try better posting the next time

Comment: @MatusSpita There is no need to apologize. We have all been new here and all made the same mistakes. I strongly advise you to do the [tour] and have a look at [ask] and check out [mcve]. In any case, Welcome to Stack Overflow.