# Understanding syntax for print multiple lines after pattern match

Tags: awk

To print multiple(2) lines following the pattern using awk:

I have found somewhere the following solution

```
$ awk '/Linux/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x){print}' file
Linux
Solaris
Aix
```

I am trying to understand the syntax

Generally awk syntax is

```
awk 'pattern{action}' file
```

Here we find

```
pattern = /Linux/
action = {x=NR+2}
```

then what is `(NR<=x){print}`

**Solution:**

My understaning of c-like syntax for this is:

```
While read (file,line)
{
  if (line ~ '/pattern/') then
  {
    x= NR+2
  }
  if (NR <= x)
   {
     print
   {
}
```

for NR=1 and if (line ~ '/pattern/') then x is set to NR+2 eg(1+2 =3). This value will not be reset till the process is over. SO when the next line is read and !(line ~ '/pattern/') then x is still 3, (NR (2) <= 3) is true so it prints the next line
Thanks to @Edmorton for the undestating

Comment: I assume that you can reduce the syntax to the following: `awk '/Linux/{x=NR+2} NR<=x' file`

Comment: [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) will explain built in variables like `NR`, etc. Good luck.

Comment: I mean generally i found `awk '/linux/{x=NR+2; NR <=x; print}`. `patter{execution code}`. Also i dont understant what is the point of `NR <=x`  if `x = NR+2`. Also how does this print 2 lines after the match, if this is executed only once

Comment: I am trying to understand how things flow. First it finds the pattern match and stores in $0, then how it loops further without any `for loop` here

Comment: @EdMorton can you also explain the c like syntax for my question What i undestand is `while read (file,line) {if (line ~ '/Linux/') then { x = NR + 2; print}}` I dont understand how (NR<=x) work

Comment: great. So basically till the time it finds `line` again it x will be NR+2, rather than getting reset. THankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW I wouldn't write the code you're asking about, instead I'd write:

```
awk '/Linux/{c=3} c&&c--' file
```

See example "g" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001.

Having said that, your original code in C-like syntax would be:

```
NR=0
x=0
While read (file,line)
{
  NR++
  if (line ~ "Linux") {
    x = NR+2
  }
  if (NR <= x) {
    print
  }
}
```

Btw, I know it's frequently mis-used but don't use the word "pattern" in your software as it's highly ambiguous - use string or regexp or condition (or in shell but not awk, sed, grep, etc. and only where appropriate "globbing pattern"), whichever it is you really mean.

For example you wrote that awk syntax is:

```
awk 'pattern{action}' file
```

No. Or maybe, depending on what you think "pattern" means! Despite what many books, tutorials, etc. say so as to remove any ambiguity you should simply think of awk syntax as:

```
awk 'condition{action}' file
```

where `condition` can be any of:

1. a key word like `BEGIN` or `END`
2. an arithmetic expression like `var < 7` or `NF` or `1`
3. a regexp comparison like `$0 ~ "foo"` or `$0 ~ /foo/` or `/foo/` or `$0 ~ var` or `match($0,/foo/)`
4. a string comparison like `$0 == "foo"` or `index($0,"foo")`
5. nothing at all in which case it's assumed to be `true` when there's an associated action block.

and probably other things I'm forgetting to list.

Comment: i was looking for this kind of flow

Answer (score 0):

your script has two blocks

```
$ awk '/Linux/ {x=NR+2}
       NR<=x   {print}' file
```

first block sets the variable `x`, second uses to print the lines.  Note that you can drop `{print}`, since it's the default action.

Comment: But second block needs to be  inside {} (braces). I mean generally i found `awk '/linux/{x=NR+2; NR <=x; print}`. Also i dont understant what is the point of `NR <=x`  if `x = NR+2`

Comment: No, two blocks are independent from each other.