# match a pattern and delete 3 lines before pattern along with the matched pattern line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

Trying to delete 4 lines in a file.
First want to delete the Pattern matched line, along with it also need to delete 3 lines before the pattern match.

```
Eg:
1.land service=bus
2.land service=car
3.land service=truck
4.land service=cycle
5.
6.air service=plane
7.air service=rocket
```

My pattern match is in line 6. (i.e: air service=plane) based on that i need to delete line's 6,5,4,and 3.

```
My output looks like.
1.land service=bus
2.land service=car
3.air service=rocket
```

Tried the below code:
    grep -B2 'air service=plane' pattern.txt | sed -n '1,3p'

i am trying to use sed and awk to delete these lines in a file, could you please advise the best method to do so.

Comment: grep -B2 'air service=plane' pattern.txt | sed -n '1,3p'

Comment: Add that to the question description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Comment: Have a look at this excellent exhaustive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/8344060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `tac` and `sed` like this:

```
tac file | sed '/air service=plane/,+3d' | tac
```

To save changes, use a temporary file:

```
tac file | sed '/air service=plane/,+3d' | tac > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tac yourfile.txt | sed "/air service=plane/{N;N;N;d}" | tac
```

explanation:

```
tac yourfile.txt               # reverse file

sed "/air service=plane/       # find pattern
{N;N;N;d}"                     # concatenate next 3 lines (N) and delete (d)

tac                            # reverse output
```

output

```
1.land service=bus
2.land service=car
7.air service=rocket
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. how you modify the file. this doesnot modfies the file.