# grep -v multiple line same time

Tags: awk, grep

I would like to filter the lines containing "pattern" **and** the following 5 lines.

Something like `grep -v -A 5 'pattern' myfile.txt` with output:

```
other
other
other
other
other
other
```

I'm interested in linux shell solutions, grep, awk, sed...
Thx

myfile.txt:

```
other
other
other
pattern
follow1
follow2
follow3
follow4
follow5
other
other
other
pattern
follow1
follow2
follow3
follow4
follow5
other
other
other
other
other
other
```

Comment: This give me the "bad" part:
"pattern
follow1
follow2
follow3
follow4
follow5", i need "other,other,other"

Comment: Yes. I need the line with "other" contents

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001, pick the one you need and massage to suit (hint - negate `g`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/{c=5;next} !(c&&c--)' file
```

Basically: We are decreasing the integer `c` on every row of input. We are printing lines when `c` is `0`. *(see below) Note: `c` will be automatically initialized with `0` by awk upon it's first usage.

When the word `pattern` is found, we set `c` to `5` which makes `c--<=0` false for 5 lines and makes awk not print those lines.

---

* We could bascially use `c--<=0` to check if `c` is less or equal than `0`. But when there are many(!) lines between the occurrences of the word `pattern`, `c` could overflow. To avoid that, [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108549/grep-v-multiple-line-same-time/56108661#comment98851023_56108661) suggested to implement the check like this:

```
!(c&&c--)
```

This will check if `c` is *trueish* (greater zero) and only then decrement `c`. `c` will never be less than `0` and therefore not overflow. The inversion of this check `!(...)` makes `awk` print the correct lines.

---

Side-note: Normally you would use the word `regexp` if you mean a regular expression, not `pattern`.

Comment: change that to `!(c&&c--)` and I'll delete my answer. with huge files `c--` will be a problem

Comment: @oguzismail You should keep yours. Thanks for the hint!!

Comment: I would if this wasn't the millionth time this question asked, but nah, thanks

Comment: Please change `pattern` to `regexp`. We're not knitting a sweater :-).

Comment: I know you are picky about this and I'm normally using `regexp` when I mean a regular expression. In this case it's just that the OP used the word `pattern` in the question and keeping it makes my example executable with the given input.

Comment: I rephrased this a bit to make clear that I'm referring to the literal word `pattern` and added a note ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed` (should be okay as `Linux` is mentioned by OP)

```
sed '/pattern/,+5d' ip.txt
```

which deletes the lines matching the given regex and 5 lines that follow

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this:

```
head -$(wc -l myfile.txt | awk '{print $1-5 }') myfile.txt | grep -v "whatever"
```

which means:

```
wc -l myfile.txt    : how many lines (but it also shows the filename)
awk '{print $1}'    : only show the amount of lines
awk '{print $1-5 }' : we don't want the last five lines
head ...            : show the first ... lines (which means, leave out the last five)
grep -v "..."       : this part you know :-)
```