# Get the line number of the first line matching second pattern

Tags: awk, sed

Is it possible using `awk` or `sed` to get the line number of a line such that it is the first line matching a regex after another line matching another regex?

In other words:

1. Find line l1 matching regex r1. l1 is the first line matching r1.
2. Find line l2 **below** l1. l2 matches regex r2. l2 is the first line matching r2, ignoring lines l1 and above.

Clarification: By match I mean partial match, for most general solution.
A partial match can of course be turned into a full-word match with `\<...\>` or a full-line match with `^...$`.

Example input:

```
- - '787928'
  - stuff
- - '810790'
  - more stuff
- - '787927'
  - yet more stuff
- - '828055'
  - some more stuff
- - '828472'
  - some other stuff
```

If r1 is `^-.*787927.*` and r2 is `^-` I'd expect the output to be 7, i.e. the number of the line that says `- - '828055'`.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Don't use the word `pattern` as it's highly ambiguous. Instead use the word `regexp` or `string`, whichever it is you mean, and clarify if you want partial, full-word, or full-line matches or something else. Additionally - whatever it is you're trying to do post concise, testable sample input and expected output that full covers all your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Input example :

```
world
zekfzlefkzl
fezekzevnkzjnz
hello
zeniznejkglz
world
eznkflznfkel
hello
zenilzligeegz
world
```

Command :

```
pat1="hello"; pat2="world";
awk -v pat1=$pat1 -v pat2=$pat2 '$0 ~ pat1{pat1_match = 1}($0 ~ pat2)&&pat1_match{print NR; exit}' <input>
```

Output :

```
6
```

Comment: A tiny bit shorter: `awk '/hello/,/world/ { if ($0 ~ /world/) {print NR; exit } }'`

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know record ranges. For those like me who want to learn more about it : https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html . Great solution

Comment: `awk '/hello/,/world/{a=NR;next}a{print a; exit}'`

Comment: This will fail if "world" is on the last line.

Comment: But to quote [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#comment92813185_17914105): _Never use range expressions (e.g. `/start/,/end/`) as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require duplicate conditions or a complete rewrite for the tiniest requirements change._

Comment: Ed Morton sure is wise. Thanks for showing me this trick anyway.

Answer (score 3):

For an input file that looks like this:

```
 1  pat2
 2  x
 3  pat1
 4  x
 5  pat2
 6  x
 7  pat1
 8  x
 9  pat2
```

you could use sed as follows:

```
$ sed -n '/pat1/,${/pat2/{=;q;};}' infile
5
```

which works like this:

```
sed -n '       # suppress output with -n
/pat1/,$ {     # for all lines from the first occurrence of "pat1" on...
    /pat2/ {   # if the line matches "pat2"
        =      # print line number
        q      # quit
    }
}' infile
```

---

The above fails if the first occurrence of `pat1` is on the same line as `pat2`:

```
 1  pat2
 2  x
 3  pat1 pat2
 4  x
 5  pat2
 6  x
 7  pat1
 8  x
 9  pat2
```

would print `3`. With GNU sed, we can use this instead:

```
$ sed -n '0,/pat1/!{/pat2/{=;q;};}' infile
5
```

```
sed -n '     # suppress output
0,/pat1/! {  # for all lines after the first occurrence of "pat1"
    /pat2/ { # if the line matches "pat2"
        =    # print line number
        q    # quit
    }
}' infile
```

The `0` address is a GNU extension; using `1` instead would break if `pat1` was on the first line.

Comment: I actually tried something very similar, but didn't know what to put in place of `{=;q;}`.

Comment: I just tested this, and it doesn't actually have exactly the right behavior. If `pat2` can match the line that was matched by `pat1` it will print that line, rather then the next match. Notice that in the question I emphasized the word **below**.

Comment: @SU3 True – a testable input and output example would have helped make that more clear.

Comment: Still, a very useful answer. If you come up with something that handles the exceptional case, please, don't remove the first solution.

Comment: @SU3 I've added a solution for that, but it requires GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^-.*787927.*/{:a;n;/^-/!ba;=;q}' file
```

On encountering a line that begins `-.*787927.*`, start a loop that replaces the current line with the next, until a line begins `-` where on print the line number and quit.