# Extract lines between two patterns and remove in between lines with if condition

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with the following content. I am trying to extract the block with matching start and end patterns, in between I want to exclude the block which has a non-matching numeric id ( maybe a pattern ). Here other than [001] has to be excluded. 002 may not be known. So, I want the blocks only matching with [001].

File contains,

```
    text [001] start
    line 1
    line 2
    text [002] mid start
    line 3     
    line 4
    text [002] mid end
    line 5
    line 6
    text [001] end
```

I need the block, with excluding nonmatching numeric id [002]'s block.

```
    text [001] start
    line 1
    line 2
    line 5
    line 6
    text [001] end
```

I couldn't get a clear clarification on the internet for this problem. Can anyone help with this, awk or sed solution?

To get the block with start and end pattern, I am trying with

```
   awk '/[001]/ && /start/, /001/ && /end/' File
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed or Perl:

```
sed '/001.*start/,/001.*end/!d;/002.*start/,/002.*end/d'

perl -ne 'print if /001.*start/ .. /001.*end/
                and not /002.*start/ .. /002.*end/'
```

Using look-ahead assertions can make the excluded tag dynamic easily:

```
perl -ne 'print if /001.*start/ .. /001.*end/
                and not /text \[(?!001).*start/ .. /text \[(?!001).*end/'
```

Comment: How to you find the 001 block, you assume just to remove 002 block.

Comment: Aha! Non-representative sample input.

Comment: It written in OPs post:   `I am trying to extract the block with matching start and end patterns`.  That would be block 001

Comment: Updated. Maybe I understood "extract" too broadly.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution that works with any other inner blocks?.  Here 002 may vary. So, I need to remove the blocks other than the 001. Means, taking 002 as the pattern may not fit. @choroba

Comment: @Megkcalb: Check the update, I used negative look-aheads to check the number of the block is different.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` may do.  You may need to tweak trigger to work for your data:

```
awk '/\[001\] start/{f=1} /\[002\] .* start/{f=0} f;  /\[001\] end/{f=0}  /\[002\] .* end/{f=1}' file
    text [001] start
    line 1
    line 2
    line 5
    line 6
    text [001] end
```

More readable

```
awk '
    /\[001\].*start/ {f=1}
    /\[002\].*start/ {f=0} 
    f;  
    /\[001\].*end/ {f=0}
    /\[002\].*end/ {f=1}
    ' file
```

Just change trigger code to reflect true data.

Comment: What if the roles of 001 and 002 are inverted?

Comment: @kvantour I guess this is just an example code.  He need a block of data, and within that block there are some thing to remove.

Comment: I think any number but `001` can appear inside and those "sub-blocks" should be removed.

Comment: Instead of sub-block, it may be referred as blocks with non-matching numeric id located within one certain block. Here 001 is a needed block and 002 is non-matching block. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Megkcalb so no one of the answer helps you.  Not giving +1 or accept one?

Answer (score 1):

Assume we make use of the variables `b1` if we are in block 1 and `b2` if we are in block 2:

```
awk '/001/ && /start/ { b1=1 }
     /002/ && /start/ { b2=1 }
     (b1 && !b2)
     /002/ && /end/   { b2=0 }
     /001/ && /end/   { b1=0 }' file
```

Range expressions are handy, but to quote [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#comment92813185_17914105): *Never use range expressions (e.g. `/start/,/end/`) as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require duplicate conditions or a complete rewrite for the tiniest requirements change.*

Comment: What if block 002 ends after block 001.  Both your and min will fail

Comment: Overlapping blocks ... fascinating. This will print still everything from block1 that does not belong to block 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your blocks are nested to any depth and just never overlapping:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { tgtId="001" }

match($0,/\[[0-9]+\]/) {
    id = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    state = $NF
}

state == "start"  { isTgtBlock[++depth] = (id == tgtId ? 1 : 0) }

isTgtBlock[depth] { print }

state == "end"    { --depth }

{ id = state = "" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
    text [001] start
    line 1
    line 2
    line 5
    line 6
    text [001] end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\[001\]/,/\[001\]/{/\[002\]/,/\[002\]/!p}' file
```

Print only lines between `[001]` delimiters and exclude those lines between `[002]` delimiters.