# awk with variable pattern with square paranthesis

Tags: awk

In my variable pattern there is square parentheses ( `abc[0]` ), but awk is unable to find pattern. If I change my pattern from `abc[0]` to `abc_0`, then it works.

```
echo "test_var=$test_var, test_var_1=$test_var_1"
# Output - test_var=abc[0], test_var_1=abc[0]

echo "$test_var" | awk -v variable="$test_var_1" '$0 ~ variable {print $variable}'
# "NO OUTPUT"  



echo "test_var=$test_var, test_var_1=$test_var_1"
# test_var=abc_0, test_var_1=abc_0

echo "$test_var" | awk -v variable="$test_var_1" '$0 ~ variable {print $variable}'
# Here Output is abc_0
```

How to find pattern variable which has square parenthesis by awk command?

Comment: I cannot recreate this after setting test_var="abc[0]". I'm assuming this is what you did?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern and  then replace "pattern" with "regexp" or "string", whichever it is you mean, everywhere in your question.

Comment: I want to do find a variable pattern by awk command . Example - echo "test abc[0]" | awk -v variable="abc[0]" '$0 ~ variable {print variable}'

Comment: **please** read the link I provided to understand why use of the word "pattern" instead of regexp or string and with no indication of partial/full matching makes your question ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

square brackets are special regex characters.

Check the following three cases, perhaps it will clarify

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{if("abc[0]" ~ /abc[0]/) print "match"; else print "no match"}'
no match


$ awk 'BEGIN{if("abc0" ~ /abc[0]/) print "match"; else print "no match"}'
match


$ awk 'BEGIN{if("abc[0]" ~ /abc\[0\]/) print "match"; else print "no match"}'
match
```

Comment: Don't forget `if ("abc[0]" == "abc[0]")` and `if (index("abc[0]","abc[0]"))`.