# Using awk to show in how many lines a pattern exist

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to see in how many lines a specific string exist.
While using `grep -c ^$string $file_name` I dont have a problem, but I need to use the 'awk' command in my project. I tried using `awk '/$string/ {print}' $file_name`, but returns 0 instead of 1. Please help me!

Comment: See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) then clarify your question by changing the word "pattern" to "string" or "regexp", whichever one you mean, and adding concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix 2 things in your attempt, 1st- How to pass a shell variable into `awk` program by using `-v` option(where `string` is your shell variable). 2nd- Use of `-c` option of `grep` to get count of string per line. To apply 2nd option use `gsub` function of `awk` to globally substitute all occurrence of str(string shell variable in awk) with its own value and keep adding the substitution value to variable count, in the `END` block of this `awk` program print the value of `count` variable which will have total number of occurrences of string per line in it for whole Input_file.

```
awk -v str="$string" '{count+=gsub(str,"&")} END{print count}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Above solution will count each and every occurrence of string's value per line, in case you need to count just always very first value of string in each line then change from `gsub` to `sub` in above program.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already, you could pass your variable to awk using the `-v` option. If you want *"to see in how many lines a specific string exist"* as `grep -c`, another option is to use match.

You could increment count by 1 for each match and return the count at the end, or 0 if there are no matches.

```
awk '
match($0, /yourpattern/) {
  count++
}
END{print count ? count : 0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
awk -v s="$string" 'BEGIN { i=0 } { index($0, s) && ++i } END { print i }' file
```