# Awk to print a single next word followin a pattern match

Tags: awk

This Q is a variation on the theme of printing something after a pattern.

There will be input lines with words. Some lines will match a pattern where the pattern will be one or multiple words separated by space. The pattern might have a leading/trailing space which needs to be obeyed. I need to print the word immediately following the match.

Example input

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Pattern : "brown fox "
Desired output : jumps
```

The pattern will only occur once in the line. There will always be a word following the pattern. There will be lines without the pattern.

awk or sed would be nice.

Cheers.

EDIT :

I failed to ask the question properly. There will be one or more spaces between the pattern and the next word. This breaks Andre's proposal.

```
    % echo -e "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n" | awk -F 'brown fox ' 'NF>1{ sub(/ .*/,"",$NF); print $NF }'
jumps
    % echo -e "The quick brown fox    jumps over the lazy dog\n" | awk -F 'brown fox ' 'NF>1{ sub(/ .*/,"",$NF); print $NF }'
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern to understand why it matters and then replace the word "pattern" with "regexp" or "string" everywhere it occurs in your question and add the information on how partial matches should be handled (e.g. does `own fox` match `brown fox`?). Once you do that we can help you come up with the right solution for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: this solution assumes that if no pattern is found (*There will be lines without the pattern.*) it is appropriate to print empty line, if this does not hold true ignore this answer entirely.

I would use `AWK` for this following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
No animals in this line
The quick brown fox   jumps over the lazy dog
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="brown fox  *"}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}' file.txt
```

output

```
jumps

jumps
```

Explanation: I set field seperator `FS` to `"brown fox "` followed by any numbers of spaces. What is after this will appear in 2nd column, I jettison from 2nd column anything which is after first space including said space, then print that column. In case there is no match, second column is empty and these actions result in empty line.

Answer (score 1):

This works, given that the desired word is followed by a *space*:

```
$ echo -e "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n" > file

$ awk -F 'brown fox ' 'NF>1{ sub(/ .*/,"",$NF); print $NF }' file
jumps
```

**Edit**:
If there're more spaces use this:

```
$ awk -F 'brown fox' 'NF>1{ sub(/^ */,"",$NF);
                            sub(/ .*/,"",$NF); print $NF }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=brown fox )(\w+)' file
jumps
```

If you have more than 1 space after the match:

```
$ echo 'The quick brown fox     jumps over the lazy dog' | grep -oP '(?<=\bbrown fox\b)\s+\K(\w+)'
jumps
```

Perl, with the same regex:

```
$ perl -lnE 'print $1 if /(?<=\bbrown fox )(\w+)/' file
```

Or, if you have multiple spaces:

```
$ perl -lnE 'print $1 if /(?<=brown fox)\s+(\w+)/' file
```

(As stated in comments, both the GNU grep and Perl regex could be `\bbrown\h+fox\h+\K\w+` which has the advantage of supporting multiple spaces between `brown` and `fox`)

With awk, you can split on the string and split the result (this works as-is for multi spaces):

```
pat='brown fox'
awk -v pat="$pat" 'index($0, pat){
            split($0,arr, pat)
            split(arr[2], arr2)
            print arr2[1]}' file
```

Comment: Unfortunately with multiple spaces between pattern and capture word this is broken.

Comment: Easy fix. Edit made.

Comment: I only tested the grep version. It is OK.

Comment: (The perl compatible pattern for grep and perl can be `\bbrown\h+fox\h+\K\w+` without the lookbehind)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, you might also use a capture group with function [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

```
\ybrown\s+fox\s+(\w+)
```

- `\y` A word boundary
- `brown\s+` Match brown and 1+ whitespace chars
- `fox\s+` Match fox and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 1**

In awk, get the group 1 value using `arr[1]`

Example

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" |
awk 'match($0,/\ybrown\s+fox\s+(\w+)/, arr) {print arr[1]}'
```

Output

```
jumps
```

See a [bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BKSQjVaGwNDM5WyGpKL88TyEtv0IhqzS3oFghvyy1SKEEKJ2TWFWpkJKfrqRQw5VYnq2gnptYkpyhoWKgox9TCdYVU6wN1AckNWLKtTX1dRQSi4o0FaoLijLzSkDsaMPYWvX//wE)