# How to get the line number of a string in another string in Shell

Tags: shell, awk, grep

Given

```
str="hij";
sourceStr="abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij";
```

I'd like to get the line number of the first occurrence of `$str` in `$sourceStr`, which should be `3`.

I don't know how to do it.
I have tried:

```
awk 'match($0, v) { print NR; exit }' v=$str <<<$sourceStr
grep -n $str <<< $sourceStr | grep -Eo '^[^:]+';
grep -n $str <<< $sourceStr | cut -f1 -d: | sort -ug
grep -n $str <<< $sourceStr | awk -F: '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
```

All output `1`, not `3`.

How can I get the line number of `$str` in `$sourceStr`?

Thanks!

Comment: You have created a variable that contains one line that includes the literal string `\n` multiple times.  Did you intend `sourceStr` to be a multiline string?

Comment: Do you want a string comparison or a regexp comparison?

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell, I meant a multiline string. I thought Shell would interpret it as a multiline string. Thanks for pointing it out and giving answers. I learned something new today!

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, It doesn't matter how I achieve the goal. I just wanted to get the line number of a matching line in the source string.

Comment: Right, my question is - what is the goal? Is it to do a string comparison or a regexp comparison? For example if `v` is `a.c` should that ONLY match `a.c` in the input (as it would with a string comparison) or should it also match `abc` (as it would with a regexp comparison)? See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more information on the different types of comparison.

Comment: @EdMorton, Oh. I got your question now. My goal was to do an exact match. So it should be a string comparison as you said. (I understood a string comparison is a special case of regex comparison. So a string comparison could be achieved by a regex match. That's why I said it doesn't matter.) Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. No to make a regexp comparison behave as it it were a string comparison is non-trivial (e.g. see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)) and pointless when you can just use a tool that supports string comparisons instead.

Comment: Ah. I may need to take back what I have said after reading your most recent reply and the page you pointed me to. So it should be a regex comparison? For string comparison, I need `\\n` to match the literal `\n`. If I meant `\n` in my `$sourceStr` for **linefeed**, I should say, I need a regex match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk + printf` in `bash`:

```sh
awk -v s="$str" '$0 == s {print NR; exit}' <(printf "%b\n" "$sourceStr")

3
```

Or even this `awk` without any `bash` support:

```sh
awk -v s="$str" -v source="$sourceStr" 'BEGIN {
split(source, a); for (i=1; i in a; ++i) if (a[i] == s) {print i; exit}}'

3
```

---

You may use this `sed` as well:

```sh
sed -n "/^$str$/{=;q;}" <(printf "%b\n" "$sourceStr")

3
```

Or this `grep + cut`:

```sh
printf "%b\n" "$sourceStr" | grep -nxF -m 1 "$str" | cut -d: -f1

3
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, Yes. All of them work in the Terminal.app on Mac. When I tried in Keyboard Maestro using the execute a Shell script, only the last one works. I got an error report: syntax error near unexpected token `('. But this is ok. I only need one that works! Thanks for offering so many solutions so that I can choose from!

Comment: `printf "%b\n" "$sourceStr" | awk -v s="$str" '$0 == s {print NR; exit}'` should also work

Comment: Hi @anubhava, Done! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you've just made a cut-n-paste error, but your `sourceStr` is not a multiline string (as demonstrated below).  Also, you really need to quote your herestring (also demonstrated below). Perhaps you just want:

```
$ sourceStr="abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij"
$ echo "$sourceStr"
abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij
$ sourceStr=$'abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij'
$ echo "$sourceStr"
abc
efg
hij
lmn
hij
$ cat <<< $sourceStr 
abc efg hij lmn hij
$ cat <<< "$sourceStr" 
abc
efg
hij
lmn  
hij
$ str=hij
$ awk "/${str}/ {print NR; exit}" <<< "$sourceStr"
3
```

Comment: `/hij/` will find `hij` in `@hijkl` as well, `==` is safer

Comment: @anubhava Agreed, but the OP uses `match($0, v)` so this is just emulating that.  But I believe the key issue here is the assignment of the string, and not the awk.

Comment: Using double quotes around any script or string opens a can of worms for robustness and security.

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell, thanks for showing me this. I did not know about this at all. So both of these will output the same result:
```
sourceStr=$"abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij";
echo $sourceStr

sourceStr="abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij";
echo "$sourceStr"
```
However, this will output `1`:
```
str=hij;
sourceStr=$"abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij";
awk "/${str}/ {print NR; exit}" <<< "$sourceStr"
```
This outputs the desired `3`
```
str=hij;
sourceStr=$'abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij';
awk "/${str}/ {print NR; exit}" <<< "$sourceStr"
```
I changed the double quotes to single quotes in the sourceStr.Why?

Comment: Sorry. The format for coding is not good. Hitting Enter cannot change lines. I had to use "Shift + Enter" to make new lines. However, they are not reflected in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sed`!

```
printf 'abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij\n' \
| sed -n '/hij/ { =; q; }'
```

Explanation: if `sed` meets a line that contains "hij" (regex `/hij/`), it prints the line number (the `=` command) and exits (the `q` command). Else it doesn't print anything (the `-n` switch) and goes on with the next line.

---

[update] Hmmm, sorry, I just noticed your "All output 1, not 3".

The primary reason why your commands don't output 3 is that `sourceStr="abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij"` doesn't automagically change your `\n` into new lines, so it ends up being one single line and that's why your commands always display `1`.

If you want a multiline string, here are two solutions with `bash`:

- `printf -v sourceStr "abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij"`
- `sourceStr=$'abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij'`

And now that your variable contains space characters (new lines), as stated by William Pursell, in order to preserve them, you must enclose your `$sourceStr` with double quotes:

```
grep -n "$str" <<< "$sourceStr" | ...
```

Comment: Hi @xhienne, Thanks for the detailed explanation. You point out the same issue my code has as @WilliamPurshell has pointed out. I tried your command in Terminal.app, but it is not working. It gives an error code: `sed: 1: "/hij/ { =; q }": extra characters at the end of q command`. I don't see any extra characters, so I don't know what was going on.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, I forgot the command separator `;`. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now! Sorry, Stackoverflow seems to allow only one checked solution and I have given it to the first reply. But yours is also very helpful. I can only check it as useful.

Comment: No problem @Martin, the one you accepted is very good (detailed and educational) and I also upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

There's always a hard way to do it:

```sh
str="hij";
sourceStr="abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij";
echo -e $sourceStr | nl | grep $str | head -1 | gawk '{ print $1 }'
```

or, a bit more efficient:

```sh
str="hij";
sourceStr="abc\nefg\nhij\nlmn\nhij";
echo -e $sourceStr | gawk '/'$str/'{ print NR; exit }'
```

Comment: `'/'$str/'...'` is exposing `$str` to the shell for globbing, work splitting, etc. so it's fragile and has security issues. To do that safely would be `'/'"$str"/'...'` but that still has other issues so just never let a shell variable expand to become part of the text of an awk script like that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for details. `echo -e $sourceStr` and `grep $str`  should be `echo -e "$sourceStr"` and `grep "$str"` too btw - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for when it's safe/appropriate to remove quotes in shell

Comment: Hi @Luuk, Thanks for your reply. It's strange that why your codes do not require double quotes to interpret the `\n` sign. I know little about the safety issue. However, since @EdMorton mentions it, I think it might better not to vote your answer up before you respond. Thanks again!

Comment: The `\n` is interpreted because of the `-e` after echo. (and, yes, Ed is right!)