# Print previous line along with matched line

Tags: awk

I want to search for pattern and if matched then print the matched line and previous line.
I used code

```
awk '/pattern/ {print a}{a=$0}' file
```

But it is only printing the previous line of matched line. How can I print print previous line along with matched line.

Comment: what should it do if the match is on the first very line?

Comment: btw: use a variable, store previous $0, update it at the end of the loop, print when needed.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `grep -B1 pattern`?

Comment: [edit] your question to replace "pattern" with "partial-or-full string-or-regexp", whatever you actually mean (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621325/1745001). Also include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Make sure it covers all of the non-obvious and non-trivial cases such as the regexp (if that's what it is) matching on the first line of input, the regexp matching on 2 consecutive lines, the regexp and input containing metachars, the regexp partial matching parts of the input, blank lines and lines of `0` in the input, etc., etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on right path, You forgot to print the current line simply do.

```
awk '
/pattern/{
  if(prev)  { print prev ORS $0 }
  if(FNR==1){ print             }
  next
}
{
  prev=$0
}
' Input_file
```

I have also taken care of 1st first line here, in case pattern comes in very first line then it will simply print that line, since there is no previous line.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
/pattern/{                            ##Checking for specific pattern here.
  if(prev)  { print prev ORS $0 }     ##Checking if prev is NOT NULL then print prev newline current line.
  if(FNR==1){ print             }     ##Checking if its first line then simply print the line.
  next                                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  prev=$0                             ##Setting prev to current line here.
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

In your current approach, when the pattern matches you are first printing `a` and then set it to the value of the current line.

The effect of this is that `a` always has the value of the previous line. If the match is on the first line, you will print an empty string as a has no value yet.

---

Besides remembering the current line in `a` and printing it in the next iteration, you also have to print the current line `$0` when the pattern matches.

```
awk '/pattern/ {
  if (a) print a
  print $0
}
{
  a=$0
}' file
```

If the value of a can also be an empty string or evaluate numerically to zero as pointed out in the comments by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), you can start printing `a` from the second row on.

```
awk '
/regexp/ {
  if(FNR>1) { print a }
  print $0
}
{
  a=$0
}' file
```

Comment: That would fail if the previous line was empty or evaluated numerically to zero.

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, I see. I think `if(FNR>1) { print a }` could solve it?

Comment: I think so, no situation comes immediately to mind that that wouldn't work for.

Answer (score 4):

You were close:

```
awk '/regexp/{print a $0}{a=$0 ORS}' file
```

See [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) and in future remember to include sample input/output in your question.