# Searching multiples patterns in a loop with awk

Tags: awk

I need to find multiple patterns in a file with awk, and count them. I don't want to write these patterns manually. I would like to know if it possible to create a "searching patterns loop"  ?

The file which contains the patterns is (I only look for the even lines) :

```
>bc1001_5p
CACATATCAGAGTGCGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAG
>bc1001_3p
CACATATCAGAGTGCGTCTCAGGCG
>bc1002_5p
ACACACAGACTGTGAGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAG
>bc1002_3p
ACACACAGACTGTGAGTCTCAGGCG
>bc1003_5p
ACACATCTCGTGAGAGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAG
>bc1003_3p
ACACATCTCGTGAGAGTCTCAGGCG
>bc1004_5p
CACGCACACACGCGCGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAG
>bc1004_3p
CACGCACACACGCGCGTCTCAGGCG
```

I would like something like that :

`awk '/the loop with all the patterns/ {count++} END{print count}' the_file_where_I_look_for_those_patterns`

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for sharing your efforts in form of code, could you please post samples of expected output in your question for making it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Actually, it will only output the number of occurences. A simple number will be enough.

Comment: Do you want exact matches or partial matches?

Comment: I want exact matches. All the "ACTG" letters will be necessary.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern and then replace "pattern" with "full-or-partial string-or-regexp" everywhere it occurs in your question so we can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want exact matches

You may try this 2 pass awk for this:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {if (!(FNR%2)) patt[$0]; next} $0 in patt' patt.txt mainfile
```

This will go through pattern file first and will store every even numbered line into `patt` associative array. In 2nd pass it will find lines same as what we have stored in `patt` array from main file.

Comment: @Paillou: Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
$ grep -Fxcf <(sed -n '2~2p' patterns_file) data_file
```