# egrep add search pattern in result

Tags: grep

I am searching multiple words in single search like below

`egrep -rin 'abc|bbc' folder`

I am want to get an output with search keyword in the result like

```
abc:folder/1.txt:32:abc is here
bbc:folder/ss/2.txt:2:    bbc is here
```

Comment: At least GNU(Linux+) and FreeBSD(Mac) versions of `grep` have `--color` (or `--colour`) which highlights the portion of the line matching the regexp in a different color if your terminal/emulator supports it -- which nearly all do today, although back in the '70s and '80s when people used a wide variety of real/hardware terminals many did not. Note for totally disjoint strings instead of `-E 'foo|bar'` you can use multiple nonextended regexps `-e foo -e bar`

Comment: Do you want the regexp you searched for or the string that matched the regexp printed? What should the output be if the regexp matches multiple times on a line? When you say `multiple words` does that mean you actually want to do full-word string comparisons instead of partial-line regexp comparisons as shown in your example?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Don't just show us the trivial, sunny day stuff - show us search strings that contain regexp metachars, matching "words" in  the input that exist on their own as well as existing as substrings of other words, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern for more information on how to ask and create a [mcve] for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some ways:

1. Post process after all the results:

```sh
grep -rinE 'abc|bbc' folder | sed '/abc/{s/^/abc:/; b}; s/^/bbc:/'
```

If there are many search terms:

```sh
$ for p in abc bbc; do echo "/$p/{s/^/$p:/; b};" ; done > script.sed
$ cat script.sed
/abc/{s/^/abc:/; b};
/bbc/{s/^/bbc:/; b};

$ grep -rinE 'abc|bbc' folder | sed -f script.sed
```

**Note** that this solution and the next one both will need attention if contents of the search terms can conflict with `sed` metacharacters.

2. Post process for each search term:

```sh
# add -F option for grep if search terms are fixed string
# quote search terms passed to the for loop if it can contain metacharacters
for p in abc bbc; do grep -rin "$p" folder | sed 's/^/'"$p"':/'; done
```

3. With `find+gawk`

```sh
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ":"
    a[1] = @/abc/
    a[2] = @/bbc/
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        if ($0 ~ a[i]) {
            print a[i], FILENAME, FNR, $0
        }
    }
}

$ find folder -type f -exec awk -f script.awk {} +
```

- If you are searching for fixed strings:

  - Change array to `a[1] = "abc"` and `a[2] = "bbc"`
  - Change the condition to `if (index($0, a[i]))`

Comment: I am doing a bulk search in multiple folders, adding search term in loop will slow down the search & search terms will be dynamic

Comment: @DyapaSrikanth there is no magic bullet, this is what I can think of. As far as I know, there's no built-in option in `grep` or alternate tools like `ripgrep` that can already do this. Use `ripgrep` for faster results since it has parallel processing built-in.

Comment: Ok, I will try this ripgrep