# Get name of matched pattern section

Tags: awk, sed, grep

There is file with lines, say

```
Sec #1 SectionA
      ..................
      ..................
      ..mypattern.......
      ..................

Sec #2 SectionB
      ..................
      .......mypattern..
      ..................
    .
    .
    .
Sec #n SectionN
```

This pattern will only be present in some sections and I would like to search on `mypattern` and get the section names (SectionA, SectionB etc..) containing the `mypattern`.

How to get it? I have tried with `grep`, `sed`, `pcre2grep`  but wasn't able to get names.

```
awk '/Sec/,/mypattern
grep -oz 'Sec.*mypattern'
pcre2grep -M 'Sec.*(\n|.)*?mypattern'
```

**Clarifications:**

- `mypattern` is just a string, no regex

Comment: Read [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) to understand  why this matters and then replace the word "pattern" with string-or-regexp and full-or-partial word-or-line everywhere it appears in your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use an empty `RS` to break down input on an empty line:

```sh
awk -v RS= '/mypattern/ {print $3}' file

SectionA
SectionB
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk will loop over all lines in input_file and for each line

- If the line starts with "Sec", set `section` to the third column of the line and set `printed` to `0`
- If the line doesn't start with "Sec", and `printed` is `0`, and the line matches "mypattern", then print the value of the `section` and set `printed` to `1`

```
awk '{
if ($1 ~ "^Sec") {
  section = $3
  printed = 0
}
else if (!printed && $0 ~ "mypattern") {
  print section
  printed++
}
}' input_file
```

If you prefer to be more concise, you could do the same thing with

```
awk '/^Sec/{sec = $3; next} /mypattern/{print sec}' input_file | uniq
```

With input file as

```
Sec #1 SectionA
      ..................
      ..................
      ..mypattern.......
      ..................

Sec #2 SectionB
      ..................
      .......mypattern..
      ..................
    .
    .
    .
Sec #2 SectionC
    ... nonmatching stuff ...
Sec #n SectionN
```

You get this output:

```
SectionA
SectionB
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Sec /h;G;/mypattern/s/.* //p' file
```

Make a copy of the section name line.

Append the copy to each line and match on `mypattern`.

If the match is successful, remove all but the section name and print the result.