# How can I parse mmcli output for modem number, identifier, and name?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This will be an easy one for most of you I think, but what is the most effective way to parse the modem number and modemmanager folder number from this:

```
root@5109910:~# mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [Sierra Wireless Inc.] Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE
```

The `ModemManager1`, `1` and `[Sierra Wireless Inc.] Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE` are dynamic and I want to be able to manipulate the modem in a shell script.

To be more specific, I'd like to generate the following:

```
MODEM_NUMBER=$(mmcli -L | grep ***PATERN TO PARSE 1 HERE***)

MODEM_DIR=$(mmcli -L | grep ***PATERN TO PARSE ModemManager1 HERE***

MODEM=$(mmcli -L | grep ***PATTERN TO PARSE [Sierra Wireles etc etc HERE***)
```

Comment: Which tool is your favorite? Can you solve any part of this problem?

Comment: I don't have a preference on grep, sed, or awk. Whichever gets the job done. I think my main issue is not understanding regex patterns whatsoever.

Comment: This is easy in sed, but you must learn the rudiments of regex and sed, or the solution will be magical gibberish like `sed 's/ .*//;s|.*/||'`

Comment: It sure looks like gibberish to me, but magical nonetheless.. Got the "1" thank you!

Comment: Step 1 - do not use the word "pattern" in the context of matching text. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) to understand the issue then replace the word "pattern" with "string-or-regexp" and "partial-or-full" and "line-or-word" everywhere it occurs in your question so we can help you get the right answer.

Comment: @DonTSpamme When you don't have a question about a specific UNIX tool, but just want to know how to do a job _using UNIX tools_, tag `unix` instead of guessing a bunch of specific tools you think someone _might possibly_ use. (An awk question should be _about awk_, a sed question should be _about sed_, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure bash you can do this in single step i.e. single invocation of `mmcli -L` command:

```sh
IFS='/ ' read -r _ _ _ mm _ mn mt < <(mmcli -L)

# chek variable's content
declare -p mm mn mt
```

**Output:**

```
declare -- mm="ModemManager1"
declare -- mn="1"
declare -- mt="[Sierra Wireless Inc.] Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE"
```

**Details:**

- `IFS='/ '`: Sets `/` or space as input field separators
- `read -r _ _ _ mm _ mn mt`: Read 4th, 6th and 7th onwards test in variable `mm`, `mn` and `mt` while ignoring rest
- `< <(mmcli -L)`: Command substitution to invoke `mmcli -L` and feed it's output to `read`

Comment: Very clever! Tested and works perfectly thank you!