# Testing it awk for data with square brackets [syslog]

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this:

```
File1   [test]
File1   sgfg
File1   fdgsfg
File1   [rsyslog]
File1   moredata
File1   MAX_EVENTS = 256
File1   fgsfg
File1   [other]
File1   Not this
File2   [syslog]
File2   extra
File2   MAX_EVENTS = 12
```

With `awk` I would like to match field $2 when it contains **[syslog]**

Example this works

```
awk '$2~/\[syslog\]/' file
```

But I like to define field in advance using var.

Not working

```
awk -v var="[syslog]" '$2~var' file
awk -v var="\[syslog\]" '$2~var' file
awk -v var="syslog" '{test="["var"]"} $2~test' file
```

This works since both sub needs to be true as well as the text match, but complicated :)

```
awk -v var="syslog" 'sub(/^\[/,"",$2) && sub(/\]/,"",$2) && $2==var' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working cases:

```
$ awk -v var='[syslog]' 'index($2, var)' file
File2   [syslog]
$ awk -v var='syslog' '$2~"\\[" var "\\]"' file
File2   [syslog]
$ awk -v var='[[]syslog[]]' '$2~var' file
File2   [syslog]
```

Basically take care of the escaping, or don't use regex matching.

As Ed kindly mentioned in the comment, `]` alone does not need to be escaped:

```
awk -v var='syslog' '$2~"\\[" var "]"' file
awk -v var='[[]syslog]' '$2~var' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The one that I will use is this `awk -v var=syslog '$2~"\\[" var "\\]"' fi le`

Comment: @Jotne  Sure thing, glad that it helped.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if you wanted a full or partial match or if you wanted a string or regexp match so here's some options:

Full string match:

```
awk -v var='[syslog]' '$2 == var' file
```

Partial string match:

```
awk -v var='[syslog]' 'index($2,var)' file
```

Full regexp match:

```
awk -v var='[[]syslog]' '$2 ~ "^"var"$"' file
```

Partial regexp match:

```
awk -v var='[[]syslog]' '$2 ~ var' file
```

There are of course, many other ways to do that too including escaping regexp metachars within the awk script to make them literal, specifying the string between `[...]` in the var then adding them in the awk script, matching just at the start or end of the field, etc.

See [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more info on the different kinds of matching and [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) (applies to awk too) for how to escape regexp metachars to make them be treated as literal.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```sh
awk -v var="[syslog]" '$2 == var' my_file
```

A bit of explanation. If you don't need regular expression matching you can just use `==` operator which compares strings literally.

Your "Not working" examples weren't working because:

1. The regular expression is not correct. It matches a single character, any of `s,y,l,o,g`.
2. Escaping is not correct, this would have worked `var="\\\\[syslog\\\\]"`. But awk should have warned you about this with the message `awk: warning: escape sequence '\[' treated as plain '['`.
3. Not sure, honestly.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but what if I would like to match it on regex, can it be done?  Example, some time I like to get all fields in square brackets, then this will not match `.*` for all.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, after looking at your examples more closely. If you want to use regular expressions - the only way is dealing with escaping which can be a pain.