# How to delete lines between two patterns(deleting inclusive of patterns) when pattern repeats

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a file that contains duplicate patterns. I want to delete all the lines between these patterns only when there are duplicate patterns.

For example, if the input file is:

```
Pattern1=File1
cat
dog
PatternEnd1
blah
blah
Pattern1=File1
fish
dog
Pattern1End
blah
blah
Pattern1=File1
tiger
dog
Pattern1End
```

The output should be:

```
Pattern1=File1
cat
dog
PatternEnd1
blah
blah
blah
blah
```

I tried using sed and doing `sed '/Pattern1=File1/,/PatternEnd1/d'` but it is deleting everything whenever the pattern matches. I want to delete everything between duplicate patterns while preserving the first occurrence.

I want to do this inside a Perl script.

Comment: Why do you tag `sed` and `awk` while you like `perl`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do it. I would use the hold space:

```
sed -n '/Pattern1=File1/{x;/^$/!p;d;};/Pattern1End/{n;h;d;};H'
```

If you encounter `Pattern1=File1`, print whatever's in the hold space (if anything) and move on. If you encounter `Pattern1End`, grab the next line and store it in the hold space, overwriting what was there. Otherwise, collect whatever you read in the hold space.

Comment: hi, apologies, I misspelt the End Patterns. Pattern1=File1..PatternEnd1 are repetitive patterns. Only the first occurrence of it should be preserved and repeating ones to be deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you could use the [flip-flop operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators). For example:

```
perl -lne 'if (/^Pattern1=File1$/ .. /^Pattern1End$/) { 
              print if !$flag } else {$flag=1; print}' file
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs. However, this code is removing all the duplicates, I want to preserve one of them and deleting all the repetitive ones  Thanks

Comment: I tested it with the input you provided (after changing `PatternEnd1` to `Pattern1End` as I assumed it was a typo (?) ) and it did not remove the first one.. What input file did you use?

Comment: I have also tested the sample file I have provided and it is working fine, but not sure why it was not working with original file I have. The solution provided with awk utility below is working for me. Many thanks for the help, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^Pattern1=File1$/ {f=f2;f1=1} !f; /^Pattern1End$/ {f2=f1;f=0}' file
```

This method means that `f` can't be set until the start and end patterns have been found in order. (Are the "patterns" meant to be regular expressions? Consider [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern))

Comment: Thank You @rowboat the awk utility did the magic for me. However when i was running in the loop it is not giving me the right results(lots of duplicates)  only when i put the unique filename it is working. As a workaround I'm redirecting the output to temporary files for every new comparison coming from the loop. Is there any way i can run it as awk loop to get rid of redirecting to temporary files. Thank You in Adavance.

Comment: Thanks I have found the way to run it in a loop, however if you could explain the logic would be really appreciable. I'm completely new to awk.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Pattern1=File1/{:a;N;/Pattern1End/!ba;x;/./{x;d};x;h}' file
```

Gather up lines between `Pattern1=File1` and `Pattern1End`.

Check the hold space to see if a flag has been set and if so delete the collection.

Otherwise, set the flag and print the collection.

Alternative:

```
sed '/Pattern1=File1/,/Pattern1End/{x;/Pattern1End/{x;d};x;h}' file
```