# "regular expression compile failed (missing operand)" issue in AWK when checking for an asterisk

Tags: kubernetes, awk

I am trying to create some useful aliases for myself and am trying to find a way see the current Kubernetes context namespace.

```
k config get-contexts

CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
 *        kubernetes-test@kubernetes2   kubernetes2  kubernetes-test    test
          kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin   default
```

I only want the output to be 'test', so I tried:

```
k config get-contexts | awk '/*/{print $5}'
```

**The error it gets**:

```
awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `*` in regex is a quantifier that means "zero or more occurrences". Since it is a regex metacharacter, it should be escaped, `\*`:

```sh
k config get-contexts | awk '/\*/{print $5}'
```

However, since you are looking for a fixed string rather than a pattern you can use `index`:

```sh
k config get-contexts | awk 'index($0, "*") {print $5}'
```

If `*` is found anywhere inside a "record" (the line) the fifth field will get `print`ed.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error message because `*` is a regexp repetition metachar and as such using it as the first char in a regexp is undefined behavior since there's nothing preceding it to repeat. You're also using a partial line regexp match when what you apparently want is a full word string match (see [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for the difference):

```
k config get-contexts | awk '$1=="*"{ print $5 }'
```