# How to count the number of files each pattern of a group appears in a file?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am having problems when trying to count the number of times a specific pattern appears in a file (let's call it B). In  this case, I have a file with 30 patterns (let's call it A), and I want to know how many lines contain that pattern.

With only one pattern it is quite simple:

```
grep "pattern" file | wc -l
```

But with a file full of them I am not able to figure out how it may work. I already tried this:

```
grep -f "fileA" "fileB" | wc -l
```

Nevertheless, it gives me the total times all patterns appear, not each one of them (that's what I desire to get).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Never use the word `pattern` when discussing matching text as it's highly ambiguous and likely to get you the wrong answer, always at a minimum state whatever combination of regexp-or-string, full-or-partial, word-or-line matching you need instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern for details then [edit] your question to replace `pattern` everywhere it occurs with the appropriate regexp/string + full/partial + word/line definition of what you're trying to match so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Count matches per literal string

If you simply want to know how often each pattern appears and each of your pattern is a fixed string (not a regex), use ...

```
grep -oFf needles.txt haystack.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

#### Count matching lines per literal string

Note that above is slightly different from your formulation *" I want to know how many **lines** contain that pattern"* as one line can have multiple matches. If you really have to count matching lines per pattern instead of matches per pattern, then things get a little bit trickier:

```
grep -noFf needles.txt haystack.txt | sort | uniq | cut -d: -f2- | uniq -c
```

#### Count matching lines per regex

If the patterns are regexes, you probably have to iterate over the patterns, as `grep`'s output only tells you *that* (at least) one pattern matched, but not *which* one.

```
# this will be very slow if you have many patterns
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    printf '%8d %s\n' "$(grep -ce "$pattern" haystack.txt)" "$pattern"
done < needles.txt
```

... or use a different tool/language like `awk` or `perl`.

---

#### Note on overlapping matches

You did not formulate any precise requirements, so I went with the simplest solutions for each case. The first two solutions and the last solution behave differently in case multiple patterns match (part of) the same substring.

- `grep -f needles.txt` matches each substring at most once. Therefore some matches might be "missed" (interpretation of "missed" depends on your requirements)
- whereas iterating `grep -e pattern1; grep -e pattern2; ...` might match the same substring multiple times.